# How to get the return value from a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, return-value, python-multithreading

The function `foo` below returns a string `'foo'`. How can I get the value `'foo'` which is returned from the thread's target?

```py
from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print('hello {}'.format(bar))
    return 'foo'
    
thread = Thread(target=foo, args=('world!',))
thread.start()
return_value = thread.join()
```

The "one obvious way to do it", shown above, doesn't work: `thread.join()` returned `None`.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

In Python 3.2+, stdlib [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) module provides a higher level API to `threading`, including passing return values or exceptions from a worker thread back to the main thread:

```
import concurrent.futures

def foo(bar):
    print('hello {}'.format(bar))
    return 'foo'

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(foo, 'world!')
    return_value = future.result()
    print(return_value)
```

Comment: For those wondering this can be done with a list of threads. `futures = [executor.submit(foo, param)                  for param in param_list]` The order will be maintained, and exiting the `with` will allow result collection. `[f.result() for f in futures]
`

Comment: @jayreed1 that comment deserves an answer of its own or it should be included in the answer. Very useful.

Comment: Wow.. thanks for the answer, was searching for multiprocessing solution for my code, but this helps me to do it in so simple way and @jayreed1 comment made it cherry on the cake, thank you all...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to fix an issue I found in some non-thread-safe libs. I liked your answer from there.        My Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982519/ansible-runner-consecutive-calls-mess-up-when-done-too-fast/68982761#68982761

Comment: I've never worked with this library before. Do I have to close the thread somehow so it won't "dangle loose", or will the executer take care of that for me automatically if I only use the code as shown here?

Comment: Note that for executing multiple futures, you can also use `executor.map()`. For example, `results = executor.map(fn, iter_of_args)`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map

Comment: with `concurrent.futures`, be very wary of deadlocks, especially when limiting the number of threads for `ThreadPoolExecutor()`. If one of threads tries to spawn another one when the pool is full, it's a full silent deadlock with no warnings.

Comment: Is `future.result()` blocking? Is there a non-blocking function to check whether the future has a result yet?

Answer (score 473):

One way I've seen is to pass a mutable object, such as a list or a dictionary, to the thread's constructor, along with a an index or other identifier of some sort. The thread can then store its results in its dedicated slot in that object.  For example:

```
def foo(bar, result, index):
    print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
    result[index] = "foo"

from threading import Thread

threads = [None] * 10
results = [None] * 10

for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i] = Thread(target=foo, args=('world!', results, i))
    threads[i].start()

# do some other stuff

for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i].join()

print " ".join(results)  # what sound does a metasyntactic locomotive make?
```

If you really want `join()` to return the return value of the called function, you can do this with a `Thread` subclass like the following:

```
from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
    return "foo"

class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args,
                                                **self._Thread__kwargs)
    def join(self):
        Thread.join(self)
        return self._return

twrv = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=foo, args=('world!',))

twrv.start()
print twrv.join()   # prints foo
```

That gets a little hairy because of some name mangling, and it accesses "private" data structures that are specific to `Thread` implementation... but it works.

For Python 3:

```
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args,
                                                **self._kwargs)
    def join(self, *args):
        Thread.join(self, *args)
        return self._return
```

Comment: thanks, i can see that that would be fine as a workaround, but it changes the function definition so that it doesn't really `return` anything.  i wanted to know in my original case, where _does_ that 'foo' actually go...?

Comment: @wim: Return values go somewhere only if you put them somewhere. Unfortunately, in the case of `Thread`, all that happens inside the class -- the default `run()` method does not store off the return value, so you lose it. You could write your own `Thread` subclass to handle this, though. I've taken a whack at it in my message.

Comment: cool, thanks for the example!  i wonder why Thread was not implemented with handling a return value in the first place, it seems like an obvious enough thing to support.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer - the OP asked for `threading`, not a different library to try, plus the pool size limitation introduces an additional potential problem, which happened in my case.

Comment: On python3 this returns ``TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given`` . Any way to fix that?

Comment: `join` has a timeout parameter that should be passed along

Comment: Warning for anyone tempted to do the second of these (the `_Thread__target` thing). You will make anyone trying to port your code to python 3 hate you until they work out what you've done (because of using undocumented features that changed between 2 and 3). Document your code well.

Comment: @GuySoft I took a look into help(Thread) and found that the Verbose can't be a positional argument -- we need to use `Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)`

Comment: @Seth You commented not on my answer, its a long thread and a mess and took me a while to hunt it myself. The line in my answer is ``Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)``. It might have changed haven't tested in a while.

Comment: Could using a mutable (like args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None) instead of like (...**args, **kwargs)) in the wrapper cause issues if you are making simultaneous calls to ThreadWithReturnValue?

Comment: this does not destroys the thread from the memory

Comment: for the first example, instead of `results = [None] * 10`, modify to pass a list of lists so that each thread has a bucket to dump to:
`threads=5`
`results = []`
`[results.append([]) for i in range(threads)]`

Comment: Thanks for this, just a remark, it seems in Python 3 version `Verbose` can be removed from `def __init__(...)`

Answer (score 368):

FWIW, the `multiprocessing` module has a nice interface for this using the `Pool` class.  And if you want to stick with threads rather than processes, you can just use the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class as a drop-in replacement.

```
def foo(bar, baz):
  print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
  return 'foo' + baz

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

async_result = pool.apply_async(foo, ('world', 'foo')) # tuple of args for foo

# do some other stuff in the main process

return_val = async_result.get()  # get the return value from your function.
```

Comment: this is the best answer as it's non-intrusive

Comment: It should be noted that in python 2.7 you can't pass objects in the args tuple. (just checked, can't do it in 3.2 either)

Comment: @CornSmith not sure what you mean... works fine for me in python 2.7.5... Just don't forget to wrap the arguments in a tuple ```(object1,)```:

```def foo2(testinstance): print 'hello {0}'.format(testinstance.bar)
class testme(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
async_result = pool.apply_async(foo2, (testme('I am bar'),))```

Comment: Well I was trying to pass a `multiprocessing.Listener()` instance. I should rephrase it that you can't pass anything that can't be pickled. I ended up just using normal threading from kindall's second answer.

Comment: Gotcha.  I didn't realize the ThreadPool pickles across thread boundaries, but that's certainly how the ProcessPool works.

Comment: I don't understand why it's accepted answer. Question was 'how to get result from thread'. Replacing module threading with multiprocessing replaces threads with processes. I hope you know difference between threads and processes? It's like killing fly from bazooka.

Comment: @omikron The *ThreadPool* doesn't spawn a new process, but has the very nice multiprocess.Pool interface.  Besides, in Python, multithreading is borked (in the sense that only one thread can run at a time) In my experience, you just end up using processes for any task w/parallel execution.

Comment: @JakeBiesinger My point is, that I was looking for answer, how to get response from Thread, came here, and accepted answer doesn't answer question stated. I differantiate threads and processes. I know about Global Interpreter Lock however I'm working on I/O bound problem so Threads are ok, I don't need processes. Other answers here better answer question stated.

Comment: @omikron But threads in python don't return a response unless you use a subclass that enables this functionality. Of possible subclasses, ThreadPools are a great choice (choose # of threads, use map/apply w/sync/async).

Despite being imported from `multiprocess`, they have nothing to do with Processes.

Comment: @JakeBiesinger Oh, I'm blind. Sorry for my unnecessary comments. You are right. I just assumed that multiprocessing = processes.

Comment: Don't forget to set `processes=1` to more than one if you have more threads!

Comment: This method has a lot of overhead!  It starts 3 managing Threads, does a lot of bureaucracy and imports piles of modules. Better simply subclass or wrap `multithreading.Thread()` and define your new run() method to save the result as ´self.ret = ...` or so.

Comment: Do not use ThreadPool. It cannot handle ctrl-C termination signal and also    does not capture stack trace when it fails. Use Thread instead.

Comment: it is way slower with tensorflow prediction. I tried running prediction task with this and it is way slower

Comment: In my opinion this answer is also relevant to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104609/1971003

Comment: Ugh, ThreadPool is broken in 3.4, it won't finish all work if one thread throws an exception. Beware if you run multiple versions of Python.

Comment: The problem with multiprocessing and the thread pool is that it much slower to setup and start threads compared to the basic threading library. It's great for starting long running threads but defeat the purpose when needing to start a lot of short running threads.

The solution of using "threading" and "Queue" documented in other answers here is a better alternative for that latter use case in my opinion.

Comment: Posted my simplified solution for saving the result below but it's pretty far down, so commenting here for visibility: stackoverflow.com/a/65447493/9983575 - This approach doesn't depend on any other modules (uses a closure function inside a `threading.Thread` subclass instead), so a lot of the concerns discussed in the comments here aren't a problem :)

Answer (score 118):

Jake's answer is good, but if you don't want to use a threadpool (you don't know how many threads you'll need, but create them as needed) then a good way to transmit information between threads is the built-in [Queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class, as it offers thread safety.

I created the following decorator to make it act in a similar fashion to the threadpool:

```
def threaded(f, daemon=False):
    import Queue

    def wrapped_f(q, *args, **kwargs):
        '''this function calls the decorated function and puts the 
        result in a queue'''
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        q.put(ret)

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        '''this is the function returned from the decorator. It fires off
        wrapped_f in a new thread and returns the thread object with
        the result queue attached'''

        q = Queue.Queue()

        t = threading.Thread(target=wrapped_f, args=(q,)+args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = daemon
        t.start()
        t.result_queue = q        
        return t

    return wrap
```

Then you just use it as:

```
@threaded
def long_task(x):
    import time
    x = x + 5
    time.sleep(5)
    return x

# does not block, returns Thread object
y = long_task(10)
print y

# this blocks, waiting for the result
result = y.result_queue.get()
print result
```

The decorated function creates a new thread each time it's called and returns a Thread object that contains the queue that will receive the result.

**UPDATE**

It's been quite a while since I posted this answer, but it still gets views so I thought I would update it to reflect the way I do this in newer versions of Python:

Python 3.2 added in the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module which provides a high-level interface for parallel tasks.  It provides `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, so you can use a thread or process pool with the same api.

One benefit of this api is that submitting a task to an `Executor` returns a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object, which will complete with the return value of the callable you submit.

This makes attaching a `queue` object unnecessary, which simplifies the decorator quite a bit:

```
_DEFAULT_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def threadpool(f, executor=None):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return (executor or _DEFAULT_POOL).submit(f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

This will use a default *module* threadpool executor if one is not passed in.

The usage is very similar to before:

```
@threadpool
def long_task(x):
    import time
    x = x + 5
    time.sleep(5)
    return x

# does not block, returns Future object
y = long_task(10)
print y

# this blocks, waiting for the result
result = y.result()
print result
```

If you're using Python 3.4+, one really nice feature of using this method (and Future objects in general) is that the returned future can be wrapped to turn it into an [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future) with [`asyncio.wrap_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wrap_future).  This makes it work easily with coroutines:

```
result = await asyncio.wrap_future(long_task(10))
```

If you don't need access to the underlying `concurrent.Future` object, you can include the wrap in the decorator:

```
_DEFAULT_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def threadpool(f, executor=None):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.wrap_future((executor or _DEFAULT_POOL).submit(f, *args, **kwargs))

    return wrap
```

Then, whenever you need to push cpu intensive or blocking code off the event loop thread, you can put it in a decorated function:

```
@threadpool
def some_long_calculation():
    ...

# this will suspend while the function is executed on a threadpool
result = await some_long_calculation()
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work; I get an error stating `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Lock'` this appears to be emanating from the line `y = long_task(10)`... thoughts?

Comment: The code doesn't explicitly use Lock, so the problem could be somewhere else in your code.  You may want to post a new SO question about it

Comment: Why is result_queue an instance attribute? Would it be better if it was a class attribute so that users won't have to know to call result_queue when using @threaded which is not explicit and ambiguous?

Comment: @t88, not sure what you mean, you need some way of accessing the result, which means you need to know what to call.  If you want it to be something else you can subclass Thread and do what you want (this was a simple solution).  The reason the queue needs to be attached to the thread is so that multiple calls/functions have their own queues

Comment: Very succinct and easy to implement (Python 2.7)

Comment: Where `@wraps` should be imported from?

Comment: @LeonardoRick it's in the functools module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Answer (score 94):

Another solution that doesn't require changing your existing code:

```
import Queue             # Python 2.x
#from queue import Queue # Python 3.x

from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)     # Python 2.x
    #print('hello {0}'.format(bar))   # Python 3.x
    return 'foo'

que = Queue.Queue()      # Python 2.x
#que = Queue()           # Python 3.x

t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(foo(arg1)), args=(que, 'world!'))
t.start()
t.join()
result = que.get()
print result             # Python 2.x
#print(result)           # Python 3.x
```

It can be also easily adjusted to a multi-threaded environment:

```
import Queue             # Python 2.x
#from queue import Queue # Python 3.x
from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)     # Python 2.x
    #print('hello {0}'.format(bar))   # Python 3.x
    return 'foo'

que = Queue.Queue()      # Python 2.x
#que = Queue()           # Python 3.x

threads_list = list()

t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(foo(arg1)), args=(que, 'world!'))
t.start()
threads_list.append(t)

# Add more threads here
...
threads_list.append(t2)
...
threads_list.append(t3)
...

# Join all the threads
for t in threads_list:
    t.join()

# Check thread's return value
while not que.empty():
    result = que.get()
    print result         # Python 2.x
    #print(result)       # Python 3.x
```

Comment: t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(foo(arg1)), args=(que, 'world!')) whats q.put doing here, what does the Queue.Queue() does

Comment: que = Queue.Queue() - creates a queue
q.put(foo) - inserts foo() into the queue

Comment: For Python3, need to change to `from queue import Queue`.

Comment: This seems to be the least disruptive method (no need to dramatically restructure the original code base) to allow return value coming back to the main thread.

Comment: But there is uncertainty  in order of the threads to be executed.

Comment: @AnandeshSharma this is generally true for every multithreaded code, but it is unrelated to the question/answer. If you need specific info about a thread, you can always put it in the return value.

Comment: Python 3: That doesn't work, the first example. It keeps returning None.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich I just ran both examples with Python 3 and they both work like a charm. Make sure you comment/uncomment the relevant lines.

Comment: @Arik yeah, I ran it again and it works perfectly.

Comment: can you explain what is the use of arg1? my code is totally different and I didn't get this part.

Comment: @Jawad The lambda is the target of the thread. Lambda has 2 arguments: q and arg1.
Then we pass two arguments to lambda: `args=(que, 'world!')`
Eventually, arg1 is the input to the foo() function, `world1` in this example.

Comment: and if it has more than 1 argument, how are the arguments passed in the queue?

Comment: @FedericoDavid here is an example with two arguments:

`t = Thread(target=lambda q, arg1, arg2: q.put(foo(arg1, arg2)), args=(que, 'world!', 'scond_argument'))`

Answer (score 55):

**UPDATE:**

I think there's a significantly simpler and more concise way to save the result of the thread, and in a way that keeps the interface virtually identical to the `threading.Thread` class (please let me know if there are edge cases - I haven't tested as much as my original post below):

```
import threading

class ConciseResult(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

[To be robust and avoid potential errors](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/928752ce4c23f47d3175dd47ecacf08d86a99c9d/Lib/threading.py#L987):

```
import threading

class ConciseRobustResult(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            if self._target is not None:
                self.result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        finally:
            # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
            # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
            del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
```

Short explanation: we override **only** the `run` method of `threading.Thread`, and modify **nothing** else. This allows us to use everything else the `threading.Thread` class does for us, without needing to worry about missing potential edge cases such as [`_private` attribute assignments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/928752ce4c23f47d3175dd47ecacf08d86a99c9d/Lib/threading.py#L902) or [custom attribute modifications](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/928752ce4c23f47d3175dd47ecacf08d86a99c9d/Lib/threading.py#L892) in the way that my original post does.

We can verify that we only modify the `run` method by looking at the output of `help(ConciseResult)` and `help(ConciseRobustResult)`. The only method/attribute/descriptor included under `Methods defined here:` is `run`, and everything else comes from the inherited `threading.Thread` base class (see the `Methods inherited from threading.Thread:` section).

To test either of these implementations using the example code below, substitute `ConciseResult` or `ConciseRobustResult` for `ThreadWithResult` in the `main` function below.

**Original post using a closure function in the `init` method:**

Most answers I've found are long and require being familiar with other modules or advanced python features, and will be rather confusing to someone unless they're already familiar with everything the answer talks about.

Working code for a simplified approach:

```py
import threading

class ThreadWithResult(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None):
        def function():
            self.result = target(*args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(group=group, target=function, name=name, daemon=daemon)
```

Example code:

```py
import time, random


def function_to_thread(n):
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
            print(f'still running thread {n}')
            count +=1
            time.sleep(3)
    result = random.random()
    print(f'Return value of thread {n} should be: {result}')
    return result


def main():
    thread1 = ThreadWithResult(target=function_to_thread, args=(1,))
    thread2 = ThreadWithResult(target=function_to_thread, args=(2,))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    print(thread1.result)
    print(thread2.result)

main()
```

**Explanation:**
I wanted to simplify things significantly, so I created a `ThreadWithResult` class and had it inherit from `threading.Thread`. The nested function `function` in `__init__` calls the threaded function we want to save the value of, and saves the result of that nested function as the instance attribute `self.result` after the thread finishes executing.

Creating an instance of this is identical to creating an instance of `threading.Thread`. Pass in the function you want to run on a new thread to the `target` argument and any arguments that your function might need to the `args` argument and any keyword arguments to the `kwargs` argument.

e.g.

```py
my_thread = ThreadWithResult(target=my_function, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

I think this is significantly easier to understand than the vast majority of answers, and this approach requires no extra imports! I included the `time` and `random` module to simulate the behavior of a thread, but they're not required to achieve the functionality asked in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893968/9983575).

I know I'm answering this looong after the question was asked, but I hope this can help more people in the future!

---

**EDIT**: I created the [`save-thread-result` PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/save-thread-result/) to allow you to access the same code above and reuse it across projects ([GitHub code is here](https://github.com/slow-but-steady/save-thread-result/tree/main/python)). The PyPI package fully extends the `threading.Thread` class, so you can set any attributes you would set on `threading.thread` on the `ThreadWithResult` class as well!

The original answer above goes over the main idea behind this subclass, but for more information, see the [more detailed explanation (from the module docstring) here](https://github.com/slow-but-steady/save-thread-result/blob/main/python/save_thread_result/__init__.py).

Quick usage example:

```
pip3 install -U save-thread-result     # MacOS/Linux
pip  install -U save-thread-result     # Windows

python3     # MacOS/Linux
python      # Windows
```

```
from save_thread_result import ThreadWithResult

# As of Release 0.0.3, you can also specify values for
#`group`, `name`, and `daemon` if you want to set those
# values manually.
thread = ThreadWithResult(
    target = my_function,
    args   = (my_function_arg1, my_function_arg2, ...)
    kwargs = {my_function_kwarg1: kwarg1_value, my_function_kwarg2: kwarg2_value, ...}
)

thread.start()
thread.join()
if getattr(thread, 'result', None):
    print(thread.result)
else:
    # thread.result attribute not set - something caused
    # the thread to terminate BEFORE the thread finished
    # executing the function passed in through the
    # `target` argument
    print('ERROR! Something went wrong while executing this thread, and the function you passed in did NOT complete!!')

# seeing help about the class and information about the threading.Thread super class methods and attributes available:
help(ThreadWithResult)
```

Comment: Also just edited the answer to include a link to a PyPI module I made for this. The core code will probably stay the same, but I want to include some better usage examples and make the README a bit more detailed, so I'll incrementally add them and then update the package to 1.0.0 and `Stable` Development Status after that! I'll update the answer here after I do so as well :)

Comment: When returning a bool in a function, I got these errors: "TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable" and AttributeError: 'ThreadWithResult' object has no attribute 'result'

Comment: The `AttributeError: 'ThreadWithResult' object has no attribute 'result'` appears when the thread is still running, or did not complete due to an exception after starting the thread somewhere (this is why `if getattr(thread, 'result', None)` is in the example). The `"TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable"` error is harder to debug without a code snippet, but my guess is one of the arguments to `ThreadWithResult` is not provided correctly. Are you using keyword arguments when defining the instance of `ThreadWithResult`? If you can post a gist/snippet of your code, that would also be helpful

Answer (score 34):

Parris / kindall's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894023/4952130) `join`/`return` answer ported to Python 3:

```python
from threading import Thread

def foo(bar):
    print('hello {0}'.format(bar))
    return "foo"

class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)

        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def join(self):
        Thread.join(self)
        return self._return


twrv = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=foo, args=('world!',))

twrv.start()
print(twrv.join())   # prints foo
```

Note, the `Thread` class is implemented differently in Python 3.

Comment: join takes a timeout parameter that should be passed along

Comment: documentation states that the only methods to override should be: __init__() and run()  https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: @lmiguelmh, This is a continuation of an earlier answer that explains that yes, this messes with internals.

Answer (score 29):

I stole kindall's answer and cleaned it up just a little bit.

The key part is adding *args and **kwargs to join() in order to handle the timeout

```
class threadWithReturn(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(threadWithReturn, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self._return = None
    
    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args, **self._Thread__kwargs)
    
    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(threadWithReturn, self).join(*args, **kwargs)
        
        return self._return
```

**UPDATED ANSWER BELOW**

This is my most popularly upvoted answer, so I decided to update with code that will run on both py2 and py3.

Additionally, I see many answers to this question that show a lack of comprehension regarding Thread.join(). Some completely fail to handle the `timeout` arg. But there is also a corner-case that you should be aware of regarding instances when you have (1) a target function that can return `None` and (2) you also pass the `timeout` arg to join().  Please see "TEST 4" to understand this corner case.

ThreadWithReturn class that works with py2 and py3:

```
import sys
from threading import Thread
from builtins import super    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159479

_thread_target_key, _thread_args_key, _thread_kwargs_key = (
    ('_target', '_args', '_kwargs')
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0) else
    ('_Thread__target', '_Thread__args', '_Thread__kwargs')
)

class ThreadWithReturn(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._return = None
    
    def run(self):
        target = getattr(self, _thread_target_key)
        if target is not None:
            self._return = target(
                *getattr(self, _thread_args_key),
                **getattr(self, _thread_kwargs_key)
            )
    
    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().join(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._return
```

Some sample tests are shown below:

```
import time, random

# TEST TARGET FUNCTION
def giveMe(arg, seconds=None):
    if not seconds is None:
        time.sleep(seconds)
    return arg

# TEST 1
my_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=giveMe, args=('stringy',))
my_thread.start()
returned = my_thread.join()
# (returned == 'stringy')

# TEST 2
my_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=giveMe, args=(None,))
my_thread.start()
returned = my_thread.join()
# (returned is None)

# TEST 3
my_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=giveMe, args=('stringy',), kwargs={'seconds': 5})
my_thread.start()
returned = my_thread.join(timeout=2)
# (returned is None) # because join() timed out before giveMe() finished

# TEST 4
my_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=giveMe, args=(None,), kwargs={'seconds': 5})
my_thread.start()
returned = my_thread.join(timeout=random.randint(1, 10))
```

Can you identify the corner-case that we may possibly encounter with TEST 4?

The problem is that we expect giveMe() to return None (see TEST 2), but we also expect join() to return None if it times out.

`returned is None` means either:

(1) that's what giveMe() returned, or

(2) join() timed out

This example is trivial since we know that giveMe() will always return None. But in real-world instance (where the target may legitimately return None or something else) we'd want to explicitly check for what happened.

Below is how to address this corner-case:

```
# TEST 4
my_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=giveMe, args=(None,), kwargs={'seconds': 5})
my_thread.start()
returned = my_thread.join(timeout=random.randint(1, 10))

if my_thread.isAlive():
    # returned is None because join() timed out
    # this also means that giveMe() is still running in the background
    pass
    # handle this based on your app's logic
else:
    # join() is finished, and so is giveMe()
    # BUT we could also be in a race condition, so we need to update returned, just in case
    returned = my_thread.join()
```

Comment: Do you know the _Thread_target equivalent for Python3? That attribute doesn't exist in Python3.

Comment: I looked in the threading.py file, it turns out it is _target (other attributes are similarly named).

Comment: You could avoid accessing the private variables of the thread class, if you save the `target`, `args`, and `kwargs` arguments to __init__ as member variables in your class.

Comment: @GreySage See my answer, [I ported this block to python3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40344234/311268) below

Comment: @GreySage answer now supports py2 and py3

Comment: @GuySoft note that your answer does not include the `timeout` arg for `join`

Answer (score 26):

Using Queue :

```
import threading, queue

def calc_square(num, out_queue1):
  l = []
  for x in num:
    l.append(x*x)
  out_queue1.put(l)


arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
out_queue1=queue.Queue()
t1=threading.Thread(target=calc_square, args=(arr,out_queue1))
t1.start()
t1.join()
print (out_queue1.get())
```

Comment: Really like this sollution, short and sweet. If your function reads an input queue, and you add to the `out_queue1` you will need to loop over `out_queue1.get()` and catch the Queue.Empty exception: `ret = [] ; try: ; while True; ret.append(out_queue1.get(block=False)) ; except Queue.Empty: ; pass`. Semi-colons to simulate line breaks.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest and simplest way I've found to do this is to take advantage of Python classes and their dynamic properties. You can retrieve the current thread from within the context of your spawned thread using `threading.current_thread()`, and assign the return value to a property.

```
import threading

def some_target_function():
    # Your code here.
    threading.current_thread().return_value = "Some return value."

your_thread = threading.Thread(target=some_target_function)
your_thread.start()
your_thread.join()

return_value = your_thread.return_value
print(return_value)
```

Answer (score 8):

My solution to the problem is to wrap the function and thread in a class. Does not require using pools,queues, or c type variable passing. It is also non blocking. You check status instead. See example of how to use it at end of code.

```
import threading

class ThreadWorker():
    '''
    The basic idea is given a function create an object.
    The object can then run the function in a thread.
    It provides a wrapper to start it,check its status,and get data out the function.
    '''
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.thread = None
        self.data = None
        self.func = self.save_data(func)

    def save_data(self,func):
        '''modify function to save its returned data'''
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            self.data=func(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_func

    def start(self,params):
        self.data = None
        if self.thread is not None:
            if self.thread.isAlive():
                return 'running' #could raise exception here

        #unless thread exists and is alive start or restart it
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.func,args=params)
        self.thread.start()
        return 'started'

    def status(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            return 'not_started'
        else:
            if self.thread.isAlive():
                return 'running'
            else:
                return 'finished'

    def get_results(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            return 'not_started' #could return exception
        else:
            if self.thread.isAlive():
                return 'running'
            else:
                return self.data

def add(x,y):
    return x +y

add_worker = ThreadWorker(add)
print add_worker.start((1,2,))
print add_worker.status()
print add_worker.get_results()
```

Comment: how would you handle an exception? let's say the add function was given and int and a str. would all the threads fail or would only one fail?

Comment: +1 for thinking like I do.
Seriously - this is the least effort. And if you're coding in Python - your stuff should automatically be done in a class, so this is legit the most sensible way to go about this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Taking into consideration ***@iman*** comment on ***@JakeBiesinger*** answer I have recomposed it to have various number of threads:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def foo(bar, baz):
    print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
    return 'foo' + baz

numOfThreads = 3 
results = []

pool = ThreadPool(numOfThreads)

for i in range(0, numOfThreads):
    results.append(pool.apply_async(foo, ('world', 'foo'))) # tuple of args for foo)

# do some other stuff in the main process
# ...
# ...

results = [r.get() for r in results]
print results

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this wrapper, which comfortably turns any function for running in a `Thread` - taking care of its return value or exception. It doesn't add `Queue` overhead.

```
def threading_func(f):
    """Decorator for running a function in a thread and handling its return
    value or exception"""
    def start(*args, **kw):
        def run():
            try:
                th.ret = f(*args, **kw)
            except:
                th.exc = sys.exc_info()
        def get(timeout=None):
            th.join(timeout)
            if th.exc:
                raise th.exc[0], th.exc[1], th.exc[2] # py2
                ##raise th.exc[1] #py3                
            return th.ret
        th = threading.Thread(None, run)
        th.exc = None
        th.get = get
        th.start()
        return th
    return start
```

### Usage Examples

```
def f(x):
    return 2.5 * x
th = threading_func(f)(4)
print("still running?:", th.is_alive())
print("result:", th.get(timeout=1.0))

@threading_func
def th_mul(a, b):
    return a * b
th = th_mul("text", 2.5)

try:
    print(th.get())
except TypeError:
    print("exception thrown ok.")
```

### Notes on `threading` module

Comfortable return value & exception handling of a threaded function is a frequent "Pythonic" need and should indeed already be offered by the `threading` module - possibly directly in the standard `Thread` class. `ThreadPool` has way too much overhead for simple tasks - 3 managing threads, lots of bureaucracy. Unfortunately `Thread`'s layout was copied from Java originally - which you see e.g. from the still useless 1st (!) constructor parameter `group`.

Comment: the first constructor is not useless, its reserved there for future implementation.. from python parallel programming cookbook

Comment: Nice solution! Just for curiosity, why in the 'get' you are not simply raising exception as it is (i.e. raise ex)?

Answer (score 6):

Based of what kindall mentioned, here's the more generic solution that works with Python3.

```
import threading

class ThreadWithReturnValue(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *init_args, **init_kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *init_args, **init_kwargs)
        self._return = None
    def run(self):
        self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    def join(self):
        threading.Thread.join(self)
        return self._return
```

Usage

```
        th = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=requests.get, args=('http://www.google.com',))
        th.start()
        response = th.join()
        response.status_code  # => 200
```

Answer (score 5):

`join` always return `None`, i think you should subclass `Thread` to handle return codes and so.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a mutable above the scope of the threaded function, and add the result to that. (I also modified the code to be python3 compatible)

```
returns = {}
def foo(bar):
    print('hello {0}'.format(bar))
    returns[bar] = 'foo'

from threading import Thread
t = Thread(target=foo, args=('world!',))
t.start()
t.join()
print(returns)
```

This returns `{'world!': 'foo'}`

If you use the function input as the key to your results dict, every unique input is guaranteed to give an entry in the results

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old question, but I wanted to share a simple solution that has worked for me and helped my dev process.

The methodology behind this answer is the fact that the "new" target function, `inner` is assigning the result of the original function (passed through the `__init__` function) to the `result` instance attribute of the wrapper through something called closure.

This allows the wrapper class to hold onto the return value for callers to access at anytime.

NOTE: This method doesn't need to use any mangled methods or private methods of the `threading.Thread` class, although yield functions have not been considered (OP did not mention yield functions).

Enjoy!

```
from threading import Thread as _Thread


class ThreadWrapper:
    def __init__(self, target, *args, **kwargs):
        self.result = None
        self._target = self._build_threaded_fn(target)
        self.thread = _Thread(
            target=self._target,
            *args,
            **kwargs
        )

    def _build_threaded_fn(self, func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
```

Additionally, you can run `pytest` (assuming you have it installed) with the following code to demonstrate the results:

```
import time
from commons import ThreadWrapper


def test():

    def target():
        time.sleep(1)
        return 'Hello'

    wrapper = ThreadWrapper(target=target)
    wrapper.thread.start()

    r = wrapper.result
    assert r is None

    time.sleep(2)

    r = wrapper.result
    assert r == 'Hello'
```

Comment: I've found at least 2 errors in ThreadWrapper :

1)  "_build_target_fn" probably mean "_build_threaded_fn"

2) "self.target" does not exist, you mean "self._target"

Comment: @PierrePuiseux Sorry bout that. Fixed. Thanks and good catch!

Comment: so much underrated. This is without the unneeded inheritance, and `__slots__`-able. My guess, it's the fastest and cleanest solution. There are some missing optimizations though, like there's no need to save `self._target`, it might as well be local.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`pool.apply_async()`** of **`ThreadPool()`** to return **the value** from **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def test(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1) # Here
result = pool.apply_async(test, (2, 3)) # Here
print(result.get()) # 5
```

And, you can also use **`submit()`** of **`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`** to return **the value** from **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def test(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(test, 2, 3) # Here
print(future.result()) # 5
```

And, instead of **`return`**, you can use **the array `result`** as shown below:

```py
from threading import Thread

def test(num1, num2, r):
    r[0] = num1 + num2 # Instead of "return"

result = [None] # Here

thread = Thread(target=test, args=(2, 3, result))
thread.start()
thread.join()
print(result[0]) # 5
```

And instead of **`return`**, you can also use **the queue `result`** as shown below:

```py
from threading import Thread
import queue

def test(num1, num2, q):
    q.put(num1 + num2) # Instead of "return" 

queue = queue.Queue() # Here

thread = Thread(target=test, args=(2, 3, queue))
thread.start()
thread.join()
print(queue.get()) # '5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your target to
1) take an argument `q`
2) replace any statements `return foo` with `q.put(foo); return`

so a function

```
def func(a):
    ans = a * a
    return ans
```

would become

```
def func(a, q):
    ans = a * a
    q.put(ans)
    return
```

and then you would proceed as such

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

ans_q = Queue()
arg_tups = [(i, ans_q) for i in xrange(10)]

threads = [Thread(target=func, args=arg_tup) for arg_tup in arg_tups]
_ = [t.start() for t in threads]
_ = [t.join() for t in threads]
results = [q.get() for _ in xrange(len(threads))]
```

And you can use function decorators/wrappers to make it so you can use your existing functions as `target` without modifying them, but follow this basic scheme.

Comment: It should be `results = [ans_q.get() for _ in xrange(len(threads))]`

Answer (score 2):

GuySoft's idea is great, but I think the object does not necessarily have to inherit from Thread and start() could be removed from interface:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
class ThreadWithReturnValue(object):
    def __init__(self, target=None, args=(), **kwargs):
        self._que = queue.Queue()
        self._t = Thread(target=lambda q,arg1,kwargs1: q.put(target(*arg1, **kwargs1)) ,
                args=(self._que, args, kwargs), )
        self._t.start()

    def join(self):
        self._t.join()
        return self._que.get()


def foo(bar):
    print('hello {0}'.format(bar))
    return "foo"

twrv = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=foo, args=('world!',))

print(twrv.join())   # prints foo
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned multiprocessing pool is much slower than basic threading. Using queues as proposeded in some answers here is a very effective alternative. I have use it with dictionaries in order to be able run a lot of small threads and recuperate multiple answers by combining them with dictionaries:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading
# use Queue for python2
import queue
import random

LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
LETTERS = [ x for x in LETTERS ]

NUMBERS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def randoms(k, q):
    result = dict()
    result['letter'] = random.choice(LETTERS)
    result['number'] = random.choice(NUMBERS)
    q.put({k: result})

threads = list()
q = queue.Queue()
results = dict()

for name in ('alpha', 'oscar', 'yankee',):
    threads.append( threading.Thread(target=randoms, args=(name, q)) )
    threads[-1].start()
_ = [ t.join() for t in threads ]
while not q.empty():
    results.update(q.get())

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version that I created of [@Kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894023/12900787).

This version makes it so that all you have to do is input your command with arguments to create the new thread.

This was made with Python 3.8:

```
from threading import Thread
from typing import Any

def test(plug, plug2, plug3):
    print(f"hello {plug}")
    print(f'I am the second plug : {plug2}')
    print(plug3)
    return 'I am the return Value!'

def test2(msg):
    return f'I am from the second test: {msg}'

def test3():
    print('hello world')

def NewThread(com, Returning: bool, *arguments) -> Any:
    """
    Will create a new thread for a function/command.

    :param com: Command to be Executed
    :param arguments: Arguments to be sent to Command
    :param Returning: True/False Will this command need to return anything
    """
    class NewThreadWorker(Thread):
        def __init__(self, group = None, target = None, name = None, args = (), kwargs = None, *,
                     daemon = None):
            Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon = daemon)
            
            self._return = None
        
        def run(self):
            if self._target is not None:
                self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        
        def join(self):
            Thread.join(self)
            return self._return
    
    ntw = NewThreadWorker(target = com, args = (*arguments,))
    ntw.start()
    if Returning:
        return ntw.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(NewThread(test, True, 'hi', 'test', test2('hi')))
    NewThread(test3, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alec-cureau. below code is working fine for me.

```
import threading
import time

def helo(name):
    print("hello", name)
    time.sleep(5)
    threading.currentThread().return_value = name
    return True

t1 = threading.Thread(target=helo, args=('bhargav',))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=helo, args=('kushal',))

t1.start()
t2.start()

print(t1.join())
print(t2.join())

print( "returned", t1.return_value)
print("returned", t2.return_value)
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted but it seems like a fine solution and works. On Python 3.11, the only change would be currentThread -> current_thread

Answer (score 0):

One usual solution is to wrap your function `foo` with a decorator like

```
result = queue.Queue()

def task_wrapper(*args):
    result.put(target(*args))
```

Then the whole code may looks like that

```
result = queue.Queue()

def task_wrapper(*args):
    result.put(target(*args))

threads = [threading.Thread(target=task_wrapper, args=args) for args in args_list]

for t in threads:
    t.start()
    while(True):
        if(len(threading.enumerate()) < max_num):
            break
for t in threads:
    t.join()
return result
```

## Note

One important issue is that the return values may be **unorderred**.
(In fact, the `return value` is not necessarily saved to the `queue`, since you can choose arbitrary **thread-safe** data structure )

Answer (score 0):

[Kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894023/5033247) in Python3

```
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon)
        self._return = None 

    def run(self):
        try:
            if self._target:
                self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        finally:
            del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs 

    def join(self,timeout=None):
        Thread.join(self,timeout)
        return self._return
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know whether or not this worked for you guys but I choose to create
a global object [mostly dictionaries or nested arrays] that way a function can access the object and mutate it, I know it takes more resources but we are not dealing with quantum science,So , I guess we can give a little bit of more ram provided Ram Consumption increases linearly with CPU usage.
Here is an example code:

```py
import requests 
import json 
import string 
import random 
import threading
import time 
dictionary = {} 
def get_val1(L): 
    print('#1')
    for n,elem in enumerate(L):
        dictionary[elem]=json.loads(requests.post(f'https://api.example.com?text={elem}&Return=JSON').text)
def get_val2(L): 
    print('#2')
    for n,elem in enumerate(L):
        dictionary[elem]=json.loads(requests.post(f'https://api.example.com?text={elem}&Return=JSON').text)
def get_val3(L): 
    print('#3')
    for n,elem in enumerate(L):
        dictionary[elem]=json.loads(requests.post(f'https://api.example.com?text={elem}&Return=JSON').text)
def get_val4(L): 
    print('#4')
    for n,elem in enumerate(L):
        dictionary[elem]=json.loads(requests.post(f'https://api.example.com?text={elem}&Return=JSON').text)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_val1,args=(L[0],)) 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_val2,args=(L[1],)) 
t3 = threading.Thread(target=get_val3,args=(L[2],))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=get_val4,args=(L[3],))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
```

This program runs 4 threads each of which returns some data for some text L[i] for i in L, the returned data from API is stored in the dictionary,
It may vary from program to program whether it is beneficial or not, for small to medium heavy computation task this object mutation works pretty fast and uses a few percentages of more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Forget all that complicated solutions.

Just install a suitable package such as:
https://pypi.org/project/thread-with-results/

Answer (score -2):

I know this thread is old.... but I faced the same problem... If you are willing to use `thread.join()`

```
import threading

class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg=""

    def hello(self,bar):
        print('hello {}'.format(bar))
        self.msg="foo"


    def main(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.hello, args=('world!',))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        print(self.msg)

g=test()
g.main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Best way... Define a global variable, then change the variable in the threaded function. Nothing to pass in or retrieve back

```
from threading import Thread

# global var
random_global_var = 5

def function():
    global random_global_var
    random_global_var += 1

domath = Thread(target=function)
domath.start()
domath.join()
print(random_global_var)

# result: 6
```

Comment: And you have a race condition. That's not a solution.

Comment: Actually you're wrong. Notice the threading .start() and .join() that start and join.

Comment: Did you try your solution ? 
It cannot work because
"radom_global_var" is not "random_global_var"

Comment: I have a block of code like this running, and was the only solution I had found for my unique situation. So ya, given the conditions, the solution I offered can be quite useful.

Comment: JohnSmith2000, I came up with the same idea recently and it worked.