# Can I use Python 3 super() in Python 2.5.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, python-2.5

Can I use clean Python 3 [`super()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) syntax in Python 2.5.6?
Maybe with some kind of `__future__` import?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot use a bare `super()` call that contains no type/class.  Nor can you implement a replacement for it that will work.  Python 3.x contains special support to enable bare `super()` calls (it places a `__class__` cell variable in all functions defined within a class - see PEP [3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135)

---

***Update***

As of Python 2.6+, bare `super()` calls *can* be used via the `future` Python package. See [posita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159479/1519716) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because an earlier version of this PEP said you'd import it with `from __future__ import new_super` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

I realize this question is old, and the selected answer may have been correct at the time, but it's no longer complete. You still can't use `super()` in 2.5.6, but [`python-future`](http://python-future.org/) provides a [back-ported implementation](http://python-future.org/reference.html#super) for 2.6+:

Install `python-future` with:

```
% pip install future
```

The following shows the redefinition of `super` under `builtins`:

```py
% python
...
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info[:3]
(2, 7, 9)
>>>
>>> super
<type 'super'>
>>>
>>> from builtins import *
>>> super
<function newsuper at 0x000000010b4832e0>
>>> super.__module__
'future.builtins.newsuper'
```

It can be used as follows:

```
from builtins import super

class Foo(object):
    def f(self):
        print('foo')

class Bar(Foo):
    def f(self):
        super().f() # <- whoomp, there it is
        print('bar')

b = Bar()
b.f()
```

which outputs

```
foo
bar
```

If you use `pylint`, you can disable legacy warnings with the comment:

```
# pylint: disable=missing-super-argument
```

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot.  But you can use Python 2's [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

**Note** This is a terrible "solution", I post it only to make sure you *don't* do this at home!
I repeat: **do not do this**

One may think about using this mixin

```
class Super(object):
    def super(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self)
```

to obtain a `self.super()`:

```
class A(object, Super):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B"
        self.super().__init__()
```

yielding:

```
 >>> a = A()
 A
 >>> b = B()
 B
 A
```

**But beware:** This `self.super()` is not equivalent to `super(B, self)` - if `A` also called `self.super().__init__()`, the construction of a `B` would cause the `A` constructor to call itself indefinitely, since `self.__class__` will remain `B`. This is due to the lack of the `__class__` mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718808/321973). You can possibly work around this issue with a hidden state machine or a sophisticated metaclass that e.g. checks the actual class's position in `self.__class__.mro()`, but is it really worth it? Probably not...