# Multi-threading SQLAlchemy and return results to ObjectListView

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, sqlalchemy, wxpython, objectlistview

I have run into another issue with a program I am working on. Basically what my program does is it takes up to 4 input files, processes them and stores the information I collect from them in a SQLite3 database on my computer. This has allowed me to view the data any time I want without having to run the input files again. The program uses a main script that is essentially just an AUI Notebook that imports an input script, and output scripts to use as panels.

To add the data to the database I am able to use threading since I am not returning the results directly to my output screen(s). However, when I need to view the entire contents from my main table I end up with 25,000 records that are being loaded. While these are loading my GUI is locked and almost always displays: "Program not responding".

I would like to use threading/multiprocessing to grab the 25k records from the database and load them into my ObjectListView widget(s) so that my GUI is still usable during this process. When I attempted to use a similar threading class that is used to add the data to the database I get nothing returned. When I say I get nothing I am not exaggerating.

So here is my big question, is there a way to thread the query and return the results without using global variables? I have not been able to find a solution with an example that I could understand, but I may be using the wrong search terms.

Here are the snippets of code pertaining to the issue at hand:

This is what I use to make sure the data is ready for my ObjectListView widget.

```
class OlvMainDisplay(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, col01, col02, col03, col04, col05,
                 col06, col07, col08, col09, col10, col11,
                 col12, col13, col14, col15):
        self.id    = id
        self.name  = name
        self.col01 = col01
        self.col02 = col02
        self.col03 = col03
        self.col04 = col04
        self.col05 = col05
        self.col06 = col06
        self.col07 = col07
        self.col08 = col08
        self.col09 = col09
        self.col10 = col10
        self.col11 = col11
        self.col12 = col12
        self.col13 = col13
        self.col14 = col14
        self.col15 = col15
```

The 2 tables I am pulling data from:

```
class TableMeta(base):
    __tablename__ = 'meta_extra'
    id = Column(String(20), ForeignKey('main_data.id'), primary_key=True)
    col06 = Column(String)
    col08 = Column(String)
    col02 = Column(String)
    col03 = Column(String)
    col04 = Column(String)
    col09 = Column(String)
    col10 = Column(String)
    col11 = Column(String)
    col12 = Column(String)
    col13 = Column(String)
    col14 = Column(String)
    col15 = Column(String)


class TableMain(base):
    __tablename__ = 'main_data'
    id    = Column(String(20), primary_key=True)
    name  = Column(String)
    col01 = Column(String)
    col05 = Column(String)
    col07 = Column(String)

    extra_data = relation(
        TableMeta, uselist=False, backref=backref('main_data', order_by=id))
```

I use 2 queries to collect from these 2 tables, one grabs all records while the other one is part of a function definition that takes multiple dictionaries and applies filters based on the dictionary contents. Both queries are part of my main "worker" script that is imported by each of my notebook panels.

Here is the function that applies the filter(s):

```
def multiFilter(theFilters, table, anOutput, qType):
    session = Session()
    anOutput = session.query(table)
    try:
        for x in theFilters:
            for attr, value in x.items():
                anOutput = anOutput.filter(getattr(table, attr).in_(value))
    except AttributeError:
        for attr, value in theFilters.items():
            anOutput = anOutput.filter(getattr(table, attr).in_(value))

    anOutput = convertResults(anOutput.all())
    return anOutput
    session.close()
```

The theFilters can either be a single dictionary or a list of dictionaries, hence the "Try:" statement. Once the function has applied the filters it then runs the returned results through another function that puts each result returned through the OlvMainDisplay class and adds them to a list to be passed on to the OLV Widget.

Again the big question, is there a way to thread the query (or queries) and return the results without using global variables? Or possibly grab around 200 records at a time and add the data "in chunks" to the OLV widget?

Thank you in advance.
-MikeS

**--UPDATE--**
I have reviewed ["how to get the return value from a thread in python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) and the accepted answer does not return anything or still locked the GUI (not sure what is causing the variance). I would like to limit the number of threads created to about 5 at the most.

**--New Update--**
I made some corrections to the filter function.

Comment: Quick Update: I am still working on threading the query for SQLAlchemy and returning the results to the ObjectListView so that the GUI does not become locked and waiting. However, I was able to test Mike Driscoll's answer and was in fact able to use the VirtualObjectList view to assist a little, but using it also removed some things I wasn't sure how to re-implement on my own. As a result I reviewed my code for my 'default' query and refined it to bring down the time needed to fully populate the OLV to an average of 34 seconds. Using the filtering code in my question is much faster than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to load the entire database into memory at once. That is usually a bad idea. Because ObjectListView is a wrapper of the ListCtrl, I would recommend using the Virtual version of the the underlying widget. The flag is wx.LC_VIRTUAL. Take a look at the wxPython demo for an example, but basically you load data on demand via virtual methods OnGetItemText(), OnGetItemImage(), and OnGetItemAttr(). Note that that refers to the ListCtrl methods...that may be different in OLV land. Anyway, I know that the OLV version is called VirtualObjectListView and works in much the same way. I'm pretty sure there's an example in the source download.

Comment: I believe that I was able to find an example of using the Virtual version of ObjectListView, located at [Virtual OLV Example](https://github.com/adrianer/ObjectListView/blob/master/Examples/UsingVirtualListExample.py). I did save the files needed to run the example and I admit that it does run faster even with 100k rows than a normal OLV widget. I will work on switching over to VirtualOLV and see if it helps my current issue. I would still like to discover a way to use threads to grab the data from the db preferably in smaller segments rather than the whole thing at once.

Comment: To grab data in smaller segments from the db would require you to change your SQL queries. You'll want to tell it to fetch X number of rows at a time. I would go that route and then keep track of the user as they scroll the widget. When they get close to the end of the row, do another query to fetch another hundred rows. Or just write a loop that fetches X number of rows in the background and updates the widget appropriately.

Comment: So I switched the OLV widget to virtual and now I am still looking for a solution to my original question. A way to run the query in a thread and retrieve the results for the widget to display. I have found a few answers around that allow the GUI to remain usable while the process is running, but I am unable to grab the results for display. So far I'm thinking this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14331755/1697769 would be the easiest to implement if I can determine when the thread finishes. I'm honestly finding it difficult to wrap my head around proper threads

Comment: You would have to wait for the query to return. When the threads finishes, you will need to use something like wx.PostEvent or wx.CallAfter to send the data to the GUI. I like to use wx.CallAfter in conjunction with pubsub to pass the information around.

Comment: I apologize that it took me so long to accept your answer, it was extremely help in reducing the amount of time the main GUI thread was locked. I did run into a few issues that I am currently unable to resolve on my own to my satisfaction, so I reviewed my existing code for my default query and was able to reduce the GUI lock time to an average of 34 seconds. I will however continue looking into VirtualObjectListView and attempt to use it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to get the query to run in a thread and be able to display the results in a standard ObjectListView. I used the answer **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308906/1697769)** with some modifications.

I added the code to my main worker script which is imported into my output panel as **EW**.
Since I am not passing arguments to my query these lines were changed:

```
    def start(self, params):

    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.func, args=params)
```

to

```
    def start(self):

    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.func)
```

In my output panel I changed how I call upon my default query, the one that returns 25,000+ records. In my output panel's init I added **self.worker = ()** as a placeholder and in my function that runs the default query:

```
def defaultView(self, evt):
    self.worker = EW.ThreadWorker(EW.defaultQuery)
    self.worker.start()
    pub.sendMessage('update.statusbar', msg='Full query started.')
```

I also added:

```
def threadUpdateOLV(self):
    time.sleep(10)
    anOutput = self.worker.get_results()
    self.dataOLV.SetObjects(anOutput)

pub.subscribe(self.threadUpdateOLV, 'thread.completed')
```

the **time.sleep(10)** was added after trial an error to get the full 25,000+ results, and I found a 10 seconds delay worked fine.

And finally, at the end of my default query I added the PubSub send right before my output return:

```
wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'thread.completed')
return anOutput
session.close()
```

To be honest I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this, but as of right now it is serving the purpose needed. I will work on finding a better solution though.

Thanks
-Mike S