# How to properly execute a non-blocking task with threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, concurrency, python-multithreading

I 've written a small python class which extends 'threading.Thread' and sends an     automatic e-mail to myself using the SMTP_SSL module. However in my calling python file it seems that things happen more sequencially:

```
import sysErrorMail
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                )

returnValue = -1
myMailInstance = sysErrorMail.sysMail()
logging.debug('Starting the mail thread')

returnValue = myMailInstance.run()

logging.debug('This message should be printed before the mail thread ends')

if returnValue == 0:
    logging.debug('Success')
elif returnValue == 1:
    logging.debug('Failed')
```

The ouput is:

```
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Starting the mail thread
[DEBUG] (Worker    ) Mail thread reports that the mail was sent successfully
[DEBUG] (MainThread) This message should be printed before the mail thread exits
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Success
```

It seems that `logging.debug('This message should be printed before the mail thread ends')` waits for my other thread to end and only then prints its message. Why is this happening and how should I go about it?

EDIT: Well it seems that if I replace

```
returnValue = myMailInstance.run()
```

with:

```
returnValue = myMailInstance.start()
```

works OK however it now prints nothing on returnValue...

Comment: Calling `run` you are **not** starting a new thread. The `start()` method is the correct method to use, however it does *not* return anything useful. If you want to return a value you can put it as attribute of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of things to get your code working as you expect.

**First: Add to your thread instance an attribute `result` and some access method.**

```
import threading
class YourThread(threading.Thread):
    ...                # code you already have.
    self.__result      # code I'm suggesting.

    def get_result(self):
        return self.__result

    def run(self):
        # You have to modify the code in your run method in order to provide
        # a value for self.__result.
```

**Second: You main thread has to `wait`  for `myMailInstance` ends, and then ask for the result. So, you need to call `join` on your thread.**

```
myMailInstance.start()

logging.debug('This message should be printed before the mail thread ends')

myMailInstance.join()

if myMailInstance.get_result() == 0:
    logging.debug('Success')
elif myMailInstance.get_result() == 1:
    logging.debug('Failed')
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

As bakuriu wrote, `start()` is the correct way to run thread. But It doesn't return value, because it is unknown, the thread can run for a while to get a result. So you should get the return value using other way. i.e. this should be helpful for you:

[how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)