# Python multithreading: Obtain worker thread results in main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

On Python 3.8, I have implemented multithreading for a network I/O task in which a bunch of worker threads download some data off of the network, process it and create their individual list of results. Now, when all threads finish, I want the main thread to obtain all the worker threads' result lists and process further.

For this discussion, I've eliminated the network I/O calls and introduced some dummy code. This is how it looks:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from random import randint as ri

class DownloadWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, result_q):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.result_q = result_q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            start_val = self.queue.get()
            try:
                # dummy code. Real code has network calls here
                thread_output = [ri(0, 10) + start_val, ri(0, 10) + start_val, ri(0, 10) + start_val]
                self.result_q.put(thread_output)
            finally:
                self.queue.task_done()

def main():
    queue = Queue()  # Communication between main thread and its workers
    result_q = Queue()  # Result queue so workers results can finally be pooled together by main thread

    # Create 2 worker threads
    for x in range(2):
        worker = DownloadWorker(queue, result_q)
        # Setting daemon to True will let the main thread exit even if worker threads block
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()

    start_values = [10, 100]  # pass start value to differentiate between thread outputs
    for start_val in start_values:
        queue.put(start_val)
    queue.join()

    # Both workers tasks done. Now let's pool the results(just printing here for simiplification..)
    while not result_q.empty():
        print(result_q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works well so far but I want to know if there is a better way to pool results in main thread using multithreading in Python 3.8. I looked at [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104512/how-to-obtain-the-results-from-a-pool-of-threads-in-python) but it throws errors when I change it as per my requirement(frankly I don't understand that solution there very well).

Appreciate some pointers on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invented your own thread pooling which has has already been provided by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class in the `concurrent.futures` module:

```
import concurrent.futures
from random import randint as ri


def worker(start_val):
    # dummy code. Real code has network calls here
    return [ri(0, 10) + start_val, ri(0, 10) + start_val, ri(0, 10) + start_val]


def main():
    NUMBER_THREADS = 2
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_THREADS) as executor:
        start_values = [10, 100]  # pass start value to differentiate between thread outputs
        # method submit returns a Future instance, which encapsulates the asynchronous execution of a callable:
        futures = [executor.submit(worker, start_val) for start_val in start_values]
        for future in futures:
            result = future.result() # block until a result is returned
            print(result)
        # or you can do: results = executor.map(worker, start_values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[20, 14, 11]
[104, 104, 108]
```

Comment: Perfect! "concurrent.futures" was what I was missing till now. I was looking into the multiprocessing module instead, which seemed like offering too many features with a pretty steep learning curve for a simple task like mine. Thanks for your suggestion!