# Print value from inside thread during it's execution

Tags: python

I've just been trying to get threading working properly and I've hit a problem. The default thread module doesn't seem to be able to return values, so I looked up a solution and found this answer - [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python/14299004#14299004)

I've got this working for getting multiple threads running, but I can't seem to print any values from inside the thread until they've all finished. Here is the code I currently have:

```
import random
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

#only 2 threads for now to make sure they don't all finish at once
pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)

#should take a few seconds to process
def printNumber(number):
    num = random.randint( 50000, 500000 )
    for i in range( num ):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            print "Thread " + str( number ) + " progress: " + str( i )
        test = random.uniform( 0, 10 ) ** random.uniform( 0, 1 )
    return number

thread_list = []

#Execute threads
for i in range(1,10):
   m = pool.apply_async(printNumber, (i,))
   thread_list.append(m)

#Wait for values and get output
totalNum = 0
for i in range( len( thread_list ) ):
   totalNum += thread_list[i].get()
   print "Thread finished"

# Demonstrates that the main process waited for threads to complete
print "Done"
```

What happens, is you get 9x "Thread finished", then "Done", then everything that was printed by the threads.

However, remove the `#wait for values` part, and it prints them correctly. Is there any way I can keep it waiting for completion, but print things from inside the function?

Edit: Here is the output (a bit long to add to the post), it weirdly reverses the print order - http://pastebin.com/9ZRhg52Q

Comment: What platform are you using? I can't reproduce that behavior you're describing. It prints exactly the way you'd expect for me on Linux.

Comment: I'm on windows using it inside Maya, wouldn't have thought it'd be that much different

Comment: I just tested on Windows, and it works fine there, too. My guess is that the issue has something to do with the way stdout is handled within Maya.

Comment: Damn, that's not cool. Can't really integrate it into my code if I can't find a way of getting it working haha. Also it prints the values with the latest first (starting at thread 9 going to 0) which doesn't seem to make sense