# How to overload the __init__ function of the Thread class in python3?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to port to python3 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894023/311268). But I am not sure how to set the`Thread.__init__` function in python3.

The deceleration of a python2 `Thread.__init__` in a thread class is:

```
Thread.__init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None)
```

But python3 its:

```
Thread.__init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None)
```

Note: The ending in python3 is: `args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None)`
Part of the problem is I don't understand how to treat the asterisk `*` in the function deceleration. Explaining what it is for would also be helpful.

Just using the python2 raises: `TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given`

How should I write the python3 `Thread.__init__`?

**Update**, the python2 call in the example is:

```
Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
```

How so my logic would say this would work in python3, but it doesn't, the answer should include how to call this, or instructions how to build it, including kwargs:

```
Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon)
```

Comment: `*` forces the caller to use kwargs for everything after the star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to overload it, just be careful how you construct your `super` call (or any call up to `Thread.__init__`) to be explicit about the arguments after the bare `*` (i.e provide them in key form):

For example, if you have a `Foo` class with a signature of:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, b=30, *, c=40):
        print(b, c)
```

you'd need to provide a `c=<value>` argument whenever you invoke it. So, for example, if you overload it in a `FooChild` class by:

```
class FooChild(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, myval_1, my_val2):
        print(a)
        super().__init__(b, c=my_val2)
```

you'll need to provide the name `c` when calling `BaseClass.__init__`.

If you have `*args` and `**kwargs` you'll again just need to explicitly provide a value for `c` when invoking the child class `__init__`, i.e:

```
class FooBase(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a, *args, **kwargs):
        print(a)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Can be invoked by `FooBase(1, 2, c=30)` but not like `FooBase(1, 2, d=30)` or `FooBase(1, 2, 30)`. You **need** to pass `c` to `__init__`, it requires it.

Comment: Can't I do something involving kargs? The example I provided uses it like this: `` Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)``, where kwargs is used when calling ``Thread.__init__``

Comment: Of course you can @GuySoft, you just always need to provide `c` to `Thread.__init__`; in what way you do that is irrelevant, you just need to pass it somehow.

Comment: Ok got it all working! And I also posted the [full code answer on the thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40344234/311268)

Comment: That's great @GuySoft, upvoted. Porting popular, and somewhat complex, answers is something that more people should consider doing.