# Why can't I get the status code of this http_response?

Tags: python, multithreading, http

Why do i get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 542, in http_response
    code, msg, hdrs = response.code, response.msg, response.info()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'code'
```

---

```
import urllib2
import threading

class MyHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_response(self, req, response):
        return response.getcode()

o = urllib2.build_opener(MyHandler())
t = threading.Thread(target=o.open, args=('http://www.google.com/',))
t.start()
t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your handler you should return the `response`

```
import urllib2
import threading

class MyHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_response(self, req, response):
        return response

o = urllib2.build_opener(MyHandler())
t = threading.Thread(target=o.open, args=('http://www.google.com/',))
t.start()
t.join()
```

Because, as the error is stating, http_response is expected to return three values: `code, msg, hdrs`

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 542, in http_response
    code, msg, hdrs = response.code, response.msg, response.info()
```

But you are overriding it to return only one value with `response.getcode()`

## Get HTTP response code

To get response code, you need to handle getting return results from the Thread. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) discussion presents several methods to do that.

Here is how you would change your code to use Queue:

```
import urllib2
import threading
import Queue


class MyHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_response(self, req, response):
        return response

que = Queue.Queue()
o = urllib2.build_opener(MyHandler())
t = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(o.open(arg1)), args=(que, 'http://www.google.com/'))
t.start()
t.join()
result = que.get()
print result.code
```

The code prints `200`.

Comment: I just had to return the response but now i can't figure out how to get the response code from the thread.

Comment: @RickyWilson this, I guess, doesn't fit to the same question. But you can find a detailed discussion on how to handle responses from thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is saying is that `response` is a `str` and there is no `code` attribute in a `str`.  I suspect that `response` needs to be parsed to pull out the code.