# How to get results from threads as they complete?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

The following code starts a few threads and prints the result after they are all done:

```
import threading

results = [None] * 5
threads = [None] * 5

def worker(i):
    results[i] = i

for i in range(5):
    threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads[i].start()

# here I would like to use the results of the threads which are finished
# while others still run

for i in range(5):
    threads[i].join()

# here I have the results but only when all threads are done
print(results)
```

As mentioned in the code, I would like to use the results of the threads which are finished while others are still running. **What is the correct way to do that?**

Should I simply start a new thread which would have a `while True:` loop and continuously check for a new entry in `results` or is there a buil-in mechanism for such operations (as part of the `threading.Thread` call which would point to a callback when the thread is done)?

Comment: `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` and you can take it from there.

Comment: Might you enumerate upon that?

Comment: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python' may be your answer is here

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: thanks, I will try that way. I was hoping that there would be a direct callback mechanism (which I did not find in the docs)

Comment: @Kallz: I know how to get the result of a thread (my code is adapted from the second answer to the link you point to). As mentioned before, I was looking for a callback mechanism, if such one exists.

Comment: use  "isAlive()" method for check thread is running or completed ,first you want to use result of completed result so check result which 'isAlive()' is false and in second condition you want to check result when all thread completed so check result when 'isAlive()' for all thread is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3, [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) is a better fit than `threading`:

```
import concurrent.futures

results = [None] * 5

def worker(i):
    results[i] = i

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as pool:
    futmap = {pool.submit(worker, i): i for i in range(len(results))}
    for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futmap):
        print("doing more stuff with", futmap[fut])
```

Comment: *The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables* - excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!