# Python: How combine returned value from 2 functions and appending them into a list using thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am new to thread, I had encountered abnormal result while printing the value inside a list using thread to allow 2 functions to working at the same time and appending the result to a list. Below my code:

```
import threading
def func1():

  return "HTML"

def func2():

  return "IS FUN"

threadslist = []

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)

x = thread1
y = thread2

x.start()
y.start()

threadslist.append(x)
threadslist.append(y)

print(threadslist)
```

And here is the result for the list:

```
[<Thread(Thread-1, stopped 1076)>, <Thread(Thread-2, stopped 7948)>]
```

Why it storing the Threads object instead of storing ['HTML', 'IS FUN'] ?

Comment: The thread isn't actually capturing the return value from each function, just executing it.

Comment: You probably want to use a thread pool as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python#14299004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `threadlist` you are saving the Thread *variables*, so that is what you're seeing in your output is their representation as strings.

You can't get the return value of a function running in a different thread like that.
To do what you can either:

1. Use the `multithreading` module:

:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
def func1():
  return 'HTML'

def func2():
  return 'IS FUN'


pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

return_values = []

return_values.append(pool.apply(func1, ())) # Using apply for synchronous call directly returns the function return value.
func2_result = pool.applyasync(func2) # Using applyasync for asynchronous call will require a later call.

return_values.append(func2_result.get())  # get return value from asynchronous call to func2.

print(return_values)
```

2. Use mutable object, like a list, to save the return values:

:

```
return_values = []
def func1():
   return_values.append('HTML')

def func2():
   return_values.append('IS FUN')

# rest of your code here
print(return_values)
```

And you'll get:

`['HTML', 'IS FUN']`

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution, but for solution 1, can I use 1 pool instead of 2 pools? Because the solution got 2 pool = pool1 and pool2, thank you so much

Comment: Yes! And it's much more Pythonic. I updated my answer (Along with an `apply` example :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import threading
threading_list = []
def func1():
   threading_list.append("HTML")

def func2():
   threading_list.append("IS FUN")

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)

x = thread1
y = thread2

x.start()
y.start()

print(threading_list)
```