# Get return from a thread - return type is dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

there is thread in my program which calls a function which returns multiple values it also contains a dataframe how can i get these values? the thread is called from a for loop

```
   ml1234=threading.Thread(target=load_syscom_ascii(fleName=fl, columns=self.cols, finalcsv=self.finalcsv,
                                                       out=self.outdir))
                        ml1234.start()
                        head, dfg, df1 =ml1234.join()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: It's not Duplicate, threading can't return DataFrames, it throws a TypeError: "'DataFrame' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call the target function when creating a Thread object, pass the function and args separately, like:

`ml1234 = threading.Thread(target=load_syscom_ascii, kwargs={'fileName': fl, 'columns': self.cols, 'finalcsv': self.finalcsv, 'out': self.outdir})`

Otherwise the function will be called in the main thread immediately.

The ways to get return values from the thread are listed in this answer - [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python), as was already suggested.

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: It executes  but not returning values

Comment: You can't get return values directly from the .start or .join functions. You need to have a global object where the results will be stored, or use some other way from those listed in the answer I linked.