# Appending an item to a list using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In got this block of code:

```
def get_spain_accomodations():
    pool = Pool()
    links = soup.find_all('a', class_="hotel_name_link url")
    pool.map(get_page_links, links)

    #for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="hotel_name_link url"):
    #    hotel_url = "https://www.booking.com" + a['href'].strip()
    #    hotels_url_list.append(hotel_url)

def get_page_links(link):
     hotel_url = "https://www.booking.com" + link['href'].strip()
     hotels_url_list.append(hotel_url)
```

For some reason the hotel_url is not being appended to the list. If I try with the commented loop it actually works, but not with the map() function. I also printed hotel_url for each get_page_links call and it worked. I have no idea what is going on. Below are the function callings.

```
init_BeautifulSoup()
get_spain_accomodations()
#get_hotels_wifi_rating()

for link in hotels_url_list:
    print link
```

The code is executed without errors but the link list is not being printed.

Comment: sharing state between processes is not trivial. Why don't you create your list using `pool.map`...?

Comment: In other words, don't do `hotels_url_list.append(hotel_url)`, just `return hotel_url` from `get_page_links` and save the result of `pool.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that processes run in isolated areas of memory. Each process will have **their own instance** of `hotels_url_list` and there's no (easy) way of "sticking" those values into the parent process' list: if in the parent process you create an instance of `list`, that *instance* is not the same that the subprocesses use: When you do a `.fork()` (a.k.a. create a subprocess), the memory of the parent process is **cloned** on the child process. So, if the parent had an instance of `list` in the `hotels_url_list` variable, you'll also have an instance of `list` (also called `hotels_url_list`) in the child process BUT they will not be the same (they'll occupy different areas in memory).

This doesn't happen with *Threads*. They do share memory.

I would say (it's not like I'm much of an expert here) that the canonical way of communicating processes in this case would be a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes): The child process puts things in the queue, the parent process grabs them:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def get_spain_accomodations():
    q = Queue()
    processes = []
    links = ['http://foo.com', 'http://bar.com', 'http://baz.com']
    hotels_url_list = []
    for link in links:
        p = Process(target=get_page_links, args=(link, q,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
        hotels_url_list.append(q.get())
    print("Collected: %s" % hotels_url_list)


def get_page_links(link, q):
    print("link==%s" % link)
    hotel_url = "https://www.booking.com" + link
    q.put(hotel_url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_spain_accomodations()
```

This outputs each link prepended with `https://www.booking.com`, the pre-pending happening on independent processes:

```
link==http://foo.com
link==http://bar.com
link==http://baz.com
Collected: ['https://www.booking.comhttp://foo.com', 'https://www.booking.comhttp://bar.com', 'https://www.booking.comhttp://baz.com']
```

I don't know if it will help you, but to me, it helps seeing the Queue as a "shared file" that both processes know about. Imagine you have two complete different programs, and one of them knows that has to write things into a file called `/tmp/foobar.txt` and the other one knows that has to read from a file called `/tmp/foobar.txt`. That way they can "communicate" with each other. This paragraph is just a "metaphor" (although that's pretty much how [Unix pipes](http://neuron.tuke.sk/hudecm/Tutorials/C/special/multi-process/multi-process.html#pipes_pipe_syscall) work)... Is not like queues work exactly like that, but maybe it helps understanding the concept? Dunno, really, maybe I made it more confusing...

Another way would be using **Threads** and collect their return value, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python).