# Threads append to list

Tags: python

How can I append the thread to the response list?

```
import requests
import threading

def URLOK(url):
    page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    return url + ":"+ str(page.status_code)+"\n"

urls = ["http://www.google.com","http://www.amazon.com","http://www.amazon.ca","http://www.google.ca"]

response = []
threads  = []
for url in urls:
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target = URLOK, kwargs ={'url':url} ))
    response.append(threads[-1].start())
for t in threads:                                                           
        t.join()
for response in response:
    print(response)
```

It is adding `None` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply return from a thread like that. The `thread.start` method just starts the thread and returns `None`. Multiple solutions can be found here: [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python).

Comment: The link you provided do not show how to append to a list.