# Error while getting list from another process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I wanted to write small program that would symulate for me lottery winning chances. After that i wanted to make it a bit faster by implemening multiprocessing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

But two weird behaviors started

```
import random as r
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool



# winnerSequence = []
# mCombinations = []

howManyLists = 5
howManyTry = 1000000
combinations = 720/10068347520


possbilesNumConstantsConstant = []
for x in range(1, 50):
    possbilesNumConstantsConstant.append(x)

def getTicket():
    possbilesNumConstants = list(possbilesNumConstantsConstant)

    toReturn = []
    possiblesNum = list(possbilesNumConstants)

    for x in range(6):
        choice = r.choice(possiblesNum)
        toReturn.append(choice)
        possiblesNum.remove(choice)
    toReturn.sort()
    return toReturn


def sliceRange(rangeNum,num):
    """returns list of smaller ranges"""
    toReturn = []
    rest = rangeNum%num
    print(rest)
    toSlice = rangeNum - rest
    print(toSlice)
    n = toSlice/num
    print(n)
    for x in range(num):
        toReturn.append((int(n*x),int(n*(x+1)-1)))
    print(toReturn,"<---range")
    return toReturn

def Job(tupleRange):
    """Job returns list of tickets """
    toReturn = list()
    print(tupleRange,"Start")
    for x in range(int(tupleRange[0]),int(tupleRange[1])):
        toReturn.append(getTicket())
    print(tupleRange,"End")
    return toReturn


result = list()
```

First one when i add Job(tupleRange) to pool it looks like job is done in main thread before another job is added to pool

```
def start():
    """this fun() starts program"""

    #create pool of threads
    pool = ThreadPool(processes = howManyLists)

    #create list of tuples with smaller piece of range
    lista = sliceRange(howManyTry,howManyLists)

    #create list for storing job objects
    jobList = list()
    for tupleRange in lista:
        #add job to pool
        jobToList = pool.apply_async(Job(tupleRange))
        #add retured object to list for future callback
        jobList.append(jobToList)
        print('Adding to pool',tupleRange)

    #for all jobs in list get returned tickes
    for job in jobList:
        #print(job.get())
        result.extend(job.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Consol output

```
[(0, 199999), (200000, 399999), (400000, 599999), (600000, 799999), (800000, 999999)] <---range
(0, 199999) Start
(0, 199999) End
Adding to pool (0, 199999)
(200000, 399999) Start
(200000, 399999) End
Adding to pool (200000, 399999)
(400000, 599999) Start
(400000, 599999) End
```

and second one when i want to get data from thread i got this exception on this line

```
for job in jobList:
        #print(job.get())
        result.extend(job.get())  #<---- this line



File "C:/Users/CrazyUrusai/PycharmProjects/TestLotka/main/kopia.py", line 79, in start
    result.extend(job.get())
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can sombody explain this to me?(i am new to multiprocessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
jobToList = pool.apply_async(Job(tupleRange))
```

`Job(tupleRange)` executes first, then `apply_async` gets some  returned value, `list` type (as `Job` returns list). There are two problems here: this code is *synchronous* and async_apply gets `list` instead of job it expects. So it try to execute given list as a job but fails.

That's a signature of pool.apply_async:

```
def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None,
            error_callback=None):
     ...
```

So, you should send `func` and arguments `args` to this function separately, and shouldn't execute the function before you will send it to the pool.

I fix this line and your code have worked for me:

```
jobToList = pool.apply_async(Job, (tupleRange, ))
```

Or, with explicitly named args,

```
jobToList = pool.apply_async(func=Job, args=(tupleRange, ))
```

Don't forget to wrap function arguments in tuple or so.