# addition of two numbers to be done in parallel in python

Tags: python

Here's my code.

```
import time    
import threading    
import multiprocessing

num1 = 0    
num2 = 0

def take_numbers(num1,num2):
    print('Enter the numbers:')
    for n in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        num1 = input('Enter first number')
        num2 = input('Enter second number')

def add_num(num1,num2):
     for n in range(0,5):
         time.sleep(0.2)
         return num1+num2

t1 = threading.Thread(target=take_numbers, args=(num1,num2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=add_num, args=(num1,num2))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

I need an output where it should stop when `time.sleep(0.2)` is called and perform addition with existing number and then again go to take_numbers function and get new numbers. I am only able to input the numbers but not getting an output.
note:there is no problem with indentation.

Please help!!
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: Why are you using threads to slow down your program? What were you hoping to achieve by using threads?

Comment: I have used two threads because when one is stopped the other should execute.

Comment: Let me make it clear,First i need to take an input from user.Then simultaneously perform addition over it and while performing addition the first one should take another input,either random input or user specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input method should read the input and place it on queue. Add method will read input from queue and perform the operation. Here is the basic implementation -

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Queue   

results = []

def take_numbers(q):
    print('Enter the numbers:')
    for i in range(0,5):
        num1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
        q.put(num1)
        q.put(num2)

def add_num(q):
    for i in range(0,5):
        num1 = q.get()
        num2 = q.get()
        results.append(num1+num2)

q = Queue()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=add_num, args=(q, ))
t1 = threading.Thread(target=take_numbers, args=(q, ))

t2.start()
t1.start()
t2.join()
t1.join()
q.close()

for result in results:
    print ("result =", result)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me!! I am also implementing parallel reduction in python using min,max and sum operations . If u can help me would be a great favor. Thanks

Comment: You can use similar logic as sum, for all reductions. If the number of input parameters vary, either put list of numbers as a single items on queue or use some kind of marker on queue to know the boundary of an input to the reduction function.