# How to add n natural numbers using threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to add n natural numbers but divide it into different threads. I have implemented it. However, I am having a problem getting the sum in the end. Kindly help using synchronization, use a global variable and locking mechanism.

I have used threads. Lets suppose I want to add 30 natural numbers, and divide into three threads, each thread summing up 10 natural numbers, the answer I get is the sum of each thread, I want to get the sum of 30.

I am using Python 2.7

My code :

```
import threading


a=input("Enter first number")
b=input("Enter second number")

sum=0

def add_func(a,b):
    result=0
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        result =result + i
    print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=add_func(1, 10))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=add_func(11, 20))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=add_func(21, 30))


    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
```

OUTPUT :

```
Enter first number1
Enter second number30
55
155
255
```

Comment: Please try it yourself first and then share the problem you are facing. Thank you.

Comment: Check how to pass parameters to `add_funct`. And learn more about threading. Read [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: I don't understand why would you use threading for this. What it does is that it slows down the program.

Comment: @MaxiMouse Agreed! just wanted to implement. Thanks for the information, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Even without the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) (if you're in CPython), the threaded version of this problem is going to be slower than [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), so I'm assuming this is purely for pedagogical purposes.

Threading in Python is primarily useful for IO-bound rather than CPU-bound work (but check out the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module for CPU-bound work).

You can return results from threads in a variety of ways. One way is to pass in a result list and give each thread a unique id number which can be used to index into the list. When a thread finishes its task, it fills its bucket in the result list, which is available in the calling code after the threads all re-join.

Another way might be using a shared variable or [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to enforce mutual exclusion to shared data (if the GIL doesn't already do so...), but that feels like overkill for this situation.

Here's the code:

```
from threading import Thread
from math import ceil

def add_func(i, res, start, end):
    total = 0

    for n in range(start, end):
        total += n

    res[i] = total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 67
    b = 131
    num_threads = 4
    threads = []
    res = [None] * num_threads
    step = ceil((b - a) / num_threads)

    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(
            target=add_func, 
            args=(i, res, a, min(b, a + step) + 1)
        )
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        a += step + 1

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    print(sum(res))
```

Or here's the fast way for completeness on this particular problem:

```
a = 67
b = 130
print((abs(a - b) + 1) * (a + b) / 2)
```