# Python: Start a thread and have its returned value to a variable further down in the script

Tags: python

I am currently writing a program that is required to be as fast as possible.

Currently, one of the functions looks like this:

```
def function():
    value = get_value()
    # Multiple lines of code

    if value == "1":
        print("success")
```

I want to know, if there is a way of calling the `get_value()` function at the start of the function and instantly running the multiple lines of code and then whenever the the `get_value()` function is finishes and returns a value the value variable is updated ready for the if statement.

Thanks!

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python) may answer your question.

Comment: what if `value` is returned in the middle of executing those "multiple lines of code" ? You need to clarify the control flow

Answer (score 0):

This is what futures are for. With [the `concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), you'd do something like:

```
import concurrent.futures

# Properly, this would be created once, in a main method, using a with statement
# Use ProcessPoolExecutor instead if the functions involved are CPU bound, rather
# than I/O bound, to work around the GIL
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

def function():
    value = executor.submit(get_value)

    # Multiple lines of code

    if value.result() == "1":
        print("success")
```

This creates a pool of workers that you can submit tasks to, receiving futures, which can be waited for when you actually need the result. I'd recommend looking at [the examples in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) for more full-featured usage.

The other approach here, for largely I/O bound cases based on sockets, subprocesses, etc., is using `asyncio` with `async`/`await`, but that requires a complete rewrite of your code, and is out of scope for a short answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Quick question though. Lets say that the "Multiple Lines of Code" are done before the ```get_value()``` function is, will it wait for the result or cause the program to crash?

Thanks!

Comment: @wtreston: [The docs cover this already](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result); `Future.result()` will block if the future hasn't finished; by default it will wait forever, but you can pass a `timeout` argument to make it raise an exception if the result isn't available within `timeout` seconds. If the result is already available, it's returned immediately with no blocking.