# Flask redirect or return data from nested view function

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, python-multithreading

I am trying to run code from a view on a GET request. This code is executed in a new thread because it takes some time to run. Note that I am not joining the thread because then the view would hang.

I tried to redirect from the inner `do_work` function back to the `/task` route but with no success. Is there a way for me to get this data to a view either with a redirect? Can I use an ajax request to help me out here?

What are the drawbacks of my current design for this view?

```
@app.route("/task", methods=["GET"])
def start_task():
    def do_work(value):
        import time; time.sleep(value)
        return "finished"

    thread = Thread(target=do_work, kwargs={'value': 5})
    thread.start()
    return "started"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stick with the Python `threading` module here is a solution:

```py
import threading
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = []
results = []

def do_work(value, task_id, results):
    import time; time.sleep(value)
    results[task_id] = "finished task {}".format(task_id)

@app.route("/task", methods=["GET"])
def start_task():
    new_task_id = len(tasks)
    task = threading.Thread(target=do_work, kwargs={'value': 5, 'task_id': new_task_id, 'results': results})
    task.start()
    tasks.append(task)
    results.append(None)
    return jsonify({'task_id': new_task_id, 'total_tasks': len(tasks)})


@app.route("/task/<int:task_id>", methods=["GET"])
def task_status(task_id):
    assert 0 <= task_id < len(tasks)
    if tasks[task_id].is_alive():
        return jsonify({'status': 'running'})
    try:
        tasks[task_id].join()
        return jsonify({'status': 'finished', 'result': results[task_id]})
    except RuntimeError:
        return jsonify({'status': 'not started'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Since the `Thread.join()` doesn't return values I used the idea of threads and results lists from
this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894023/4088670).

This code creates an endpoint for each task.  The total number of tasks and the new task id are returned in
JSON, so you can leverage AJAX more easily.

But be aware of the
[Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)
which make all Python threads run on a single core.  A better solution to this problem would be to use
the `multiprocessing` module, specially the the `Pool` class (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299004/4088670)).