# How to use threading to call http API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

I have a project where I am displaying the live video feed from the USB camera using `opencv`. In between the code, there is a condition. When it becomes `True` I have to call an API to get some data which I am displaying on the live video feed frame. Calling the API and getting the response takes some time (2-3sec) during which the frame is freezed which doesn't look good. Below is the code snippet:

```
if config['ROIX1'] < f_startX and config['ROIX2']:
    # Call the API and get the response
    """
    OTHER CODE
    """

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.tive.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/get_status", json_data, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    rdata = response.read()
    rdata = rdata.decode('utf8')
    rdata = json.loads(rdata)

    subject = rdata['subject']

    txt = "SUBJECT: {}".format(subject)
    cv2.putText(frame, txt, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

In above code when the if condition becomes True, code makes a call to the API and the response `rdata` takes some time due to which the application freezes for some time. How can I effectively handle calling and getting the response from the API in another thread and once it gets the result, it is shown on `frame`. I am not very experienced in `threads`. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Believe the kind of logic you're looking for is something like:

1) start thread for requesting api

2) while requesting is not finished do some other task ( show frame without api data)

3) break while when done, (show frame with api data)

I believe the key for your answer is using thread.is_alive, which checks whether a thread is alive and returns a boolean value based on the thread status.  is_alive() method is often used in thread synchronisation.

I would do what you're looking for by doing something similar to this dummy code:

```
import sys
import trace
import threading
import time
def show_frame(subject=""):
    if subject:
        print(f"showing frame with {subject}")
    else:
        print(f"showing frame")

def request_api():
    time.sleep(5)
    return "data from api"

def show_frame_from_api():
    subject_dataAPI=request_api()
    show_frame(subject=subject_dataAPI)

t = threading.Thread(target=show_frame_from_api, args=())
t.start()

while t.is_alive():
    show_frame()
```

Applying it in your example, I would suggest something like this :

```
import sys
import trace
import threading
import time
def show_frame(win_name, frame, apiText=""):
    if apiText:
        text=f'display with {apiText}'
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)
    else
        text=f'display without api text :('
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)

def show_frame_from_api(win_name, frame):
    subject_dataAPI=request_api()
    show_frame(win_name, frame, apiText=subject_dataAPI)


def request_api():
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.tive.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/get_status", json_data, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    rdata = response.read()
    rdata = rdata.decode('utf8')
    rdata = json.loads(rdata)

    subject = rdata['subject']

    txt = "SUBJECT: {}".format(subject)
    return txt

if config['ROIX1'] < f_startX and config['ROIX2']:
    # Call the API and get the response
    """
    OTHER CODE
    """

    t = threading.Thread(target=show_frame_from_api, args=(win_name, frame))
    t.start()

    while t.is_alive():
        show_frame(win_name, frame)


    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The threading library in Python is pretty easy to use and is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

The first thing you need to do is to wrap the code that you want to run independently as a function, then you can use the library to run that function in a separate thread, as follows:

```py
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=yourfunction, args=('arg1', 'arg2'))
thread.start()
```

Note that [getting the result value from the executed function is a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python), so I would suggest you to run the whole block (i.e the API call + displaying the frame) in a separate thread. Your code should look like:

```py
def show_frame_from_api(win_name, frame):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.tive.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/get_status", json_data, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    rdata = response.read()
    rdata = rdata.decode('utf8')
    rdata = json.loads(rdata)

    subject = rdata['subject']

    txt = "SUBJECT: {}".format(subject)
    cv2.putText(frame, txt, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)
```

```py
if config['ROIX1'] < f_startX and config['ROIX2']:
    # Call the API and get the response
    """
    OTHER CODE
    """

    t = threading.Thread(target=show_frame_from_api, args=(win_frame, frame))
    t.start()

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Whether you include the `OTHER CODE` block and the `cv2.waitKey` block inside the function depends on what are you trying to achive, but you should get the idea.

Note that you shouldn't call [`t.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait for the thread to finish because that would freeze your main thread as well. As I already mentioned, the simplest approach is just to delegate to the thread all the action regarded to the API call and the processing of the response.