# Python Threading methods and getting results

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So I have a simple function that gets a webpage HTML content:

```
def loadUrl():
url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07XLGMM47"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 '
                  'Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

data = response.text
return data
```

and I'm using `Threading` to get the results of this function, and I already tested those method and it do work:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
t1 = executor.submit(loadUrl)
result = t1.result()
```

but how do I get a result using this method:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=loadUrl)
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

I tried this but no use it didn't work:

```
que = queue.Queue()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=loadUrl)
t1.start()
t1.join()
result = que.get()
```

Comment: The queue will work, but you'd need to update your `loadUrl` function to push data onto it first.

Comment: @bnaecker Oh thanks, sorry I have just started learning python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: @Mohd thank you but I didn't know I need to use the same queue, anyway thanks to bnaecker now I know