# Return value in a python thread

Tags: python, pthreads

I am new in Python and I want to get the value from a thread. I call the function logica in a thread and that function returns a value I want to know how can I get the value songs because I will use it later in an iter. Comand is a string. I am using the library threading

```
def logica_thread ( comand):
        threading.Thread(target= logica ,args = (comand,), daemon = True).start()       
 
def logica(comando):
    request = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/' + comand)
    time.sleep(5) 
    songs = request.json()['data']
    return songs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the return value from a thread in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your setup that is a little difficult because you have no reference to the thread. So

1. After starting it when is the thread ready?
2. Where to are the results returned?

1 can be fixed by assigning the thread to a variable.
2 in your case you can provide an external list for the results and pass it as argument.

```
import threading
import time


def test_thread(list):

    for i in range(10):
        list.append(str(i))


my_list = []

my_thread = threading.Thread(target=test_thread, args=[my_list])
my_thread.start()

while my_thread.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.1)

print(my_list)
```

Result

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```