# Ansible Runner consecutive calls mess up when done too fast

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-runner

I have made a piece of software using the official Ansible Runner libraries that receives several remote calls to run 1 or N times 1 or M playbooks...
The Ansible run config is sequential, although this should not be relevant for different calls (if I understand right, it just configures the tasks inside the same playbook run)

So, I run the playbooks using **Ansible Runner**'s `run_async()`:

```
runner_async_thread, runner_object = ansible_runner.run_async(
                **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

and keep a loop the asynchronous thread's `is_alive()` method, checking for other conditions

```
while runner_async_thread.is_alive():
    ...
```

If an exception is raised, or after the thread finishes, I just check the status result and return.

The issue is that, when the system receives a lot of calls together, it messes up, and I get errors such as this one:

```
The offending line appears to be:


{"username": "operator", "password": "!", "target": "sever_003_linux"}05_linux"}
                                                                      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

The error is obviously this:

```
    {"username": "new_user", "target": "sever_003_linux"}05_linux"}
```

I doble check (logs and env/extravars files), but the sent commands are right:

```
{"username": "new_user", "target": "sever_003_linux"}
```

So, it seems a memory area is being overwritten without been cleaned, could be 2 runners running together (it seems it is possible) without Thread Safety?
Do you have some idea about how to fix this or a way to prevent it from happening, please?

The code normally worked, the same calls worked when using some delays, but I don't think it is an ideal solution...

I was playing with Ansible config, but no way.

```
ansible 2.9.6
python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more people reporting about this issue in this Jira story: https://jira.opencord.org/browse/CORD-922

> Ansible, when used via its API, is not thread-safe.

They also propose an idea about how to overcome this problem:

> To be safe and avoid such issues, we will wrap invocations of Ansible in a process by invoking a fork() before using it.

But, in my case, I have to return the result of the operation to report it. Therefore, I declare a shared queue in order to communicate the processes, and I fork the main one.

```
import ansible_runner
from multiprocessing import Queue
import os

#...

def playbook_run(self, parameters):
    #...
    runner_async_thread, runner_object = ansible_runner.run_async(
                    **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
    while runner_async_thread.is_alive():
        #...
    return run_result


shared_queue = Queue()
process_pid = os.fork()
if process_pid == 0:  # the forked child process will independently run & report
    run_result = self.playbook_run(playbook_name,
                                   parameters)
    shared_queue.put(run_result)
    shared_queue.close()
    shared_queue.join_thread()
    os._exit(0)
else:  # the parent process will wait until it gets the report
    run_result = shared_queue.get()
    return run_result
```

And, assuming that the lack of thread safety was the issue, problem solved.

As I think it was not reported, I opened an issue in the Ansible Runner developers GitHub: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/issues/808