# Thread join in a loop where multiple clients can connect to a server

Tags: java, multithreading

In a program where multiple clients can connect to a server, is it a good idea to use `join`?
For example:

```
while(true)
{
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    //thread creation for new clients, followed by executing their (generally overwritten) `run()` method.
    thread.join();
}
```

Now, my understanding is, if the thread is `join`ed, then a new client will have to wait till the client before it completes the intended operation - which shouldn't be happening as multiple clients should be able to connect and operate simultaneously.

So, is it a good idea to use `join` in such a fashion?

Comment: No, it isn't a good idea: in fact it lacks all motivation. However your underlying premiss is also false: you are overlooking the backlog queue, which means that multiple clients can connect even though you haven't done that number of accepts.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a good idea to do `thread.join()` in a loop like this.

`thread.join()` will result in the current thread going into a wait state till the time the thread referenced by the variable `thread` ends.  So as such, the loop will hang there.  No new sockets will be accepted.

After accepting a socket, a new thread should be created, and the socket should be handed over to that new thread for further processing.
As soon as a socket is accepted and a ClientSocket is created, the connection is request is removed from the backlog queue. If that loop goes into a wait state, the backlog queue will also be filled up and connection requests might also be denied.

The current thread which is accepting the new connections should continue, so it should not use `join`.  It should create a new thread and continue to accept new connection requests as soon as possible so that the backlog queue is also kept relatively empty most of the time.

Only if the server is shutting down, the loop should break (not accept new connections), and then outside the loop, it can wait for the running threads to complete (complete the communication with the already connected clients), and then exit.

Comment: New sockets will be accepted up to the limit of the backlog queue.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  But the main question is, should `thread.join()` be put in the loop that accepts thew socket connections or not.  Having backlog queue limit does not affect that.  `thread.join()` should not be used in that loop in any case.

Comment: So fix your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It never makes any sense to start a new thread and then immediately `join` it. The whole point of creating a new thread is so that the new thread can do its thing while the caller *concurrently* does some other thing:

```java
Runnable r = ...;
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
doSomeOtherThingConcurrentlyWithTheNewThread();
t.join();
```

If there isn't some other thing that the caller wants to do, then there is no reason to create the new thread. You can save some CPU cycles by just doing this instead, and it will have exactly the same effect:

```java
Runnable r = ...;
r.run();
```