# How to wait for the response in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
def send_request():
    response = requests.get(url="https://www.google.com/")
    # wait for the response


threading.Thread(target=send_request, daemon=False).start()
```

I am sending the request on the background thread. How do I wait until I get the response? I don't want to call the `get()` on the main thread.

Comment: How do you wait WHERE?   Unlike Selenium, `requests` is synchronous.  It won't return until it has the response.  If you need your main thread to wait for the response, then you don't really need threading.

Comment: Your [mre] is a little _too_ minimal. Why are you using threading here at all? The natural solution would be to handle the result in the same thread where you are retrieving it.

Comment: I's not about `requets` but OP rather wants to know when thread finished whatever it was doing

Comment: That's one possible interpretation of his question.  It's not the ONLY interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Request call is synchronous, so it's not the problem as you will always need to wait. But if you use call on a thread and want to let main code know when background work is done, Python threading has various methods for thread synchronization, like events, condition variables, and semaphores, so go with one (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)).

Like with events your code would "communicate" by event's state:

```py
def send_request(event):
    response = requests.get(url="https://www.google.com/")
    # Signal that the request is complete
    event.set()

# Create an event object
event = threading.Event()

# Start the thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=send_request, args=(event,), daemon=False)
thread.start()

# Wait for the request to complete
event.wait()
```

Depending on the use case `wait()` may not be fittings as it is a blocking call, so if you want to periodically check the event state by doing other stuff, use `event.is_set()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asyncio and aiohttp to perform asynchronous HTTP requests and wait for the responses

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def send_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://www.google.com/") as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main():
    response_text = await send_request()
    # Process the response here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: You could (and better to) use `asyncio.run(main())` api instead.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution, but it's really not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get()` is a blocking call inside the `send_request` function which is started as a thread. Your response is available when `send_request` thread finishes, so simply call `.join()` on that thread in the main thread, then the main thread is wait for that thread to finish.

```py
import requests
import threading

response = None

def send_request():
    global response
    response = requests.get(url="https://www.google.com/")


t1 = threading.Thread(target=send_request, daemon=False)
t1.start()
print("Printing on the main thread after t1 started.")
print("going to wait for 'send_request' thread")
t1.join()
print("'send_request' finished. response is ready")
print(response)
```

I used a global variable for retrieving the result of a thread, but you may want to take a look at the below link for more information:

[How to get the return value from a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893968/13944524)