# Errors with quadratic formula and multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

My code:

```
import math
import threading
A = input("What is your a? ")
B = input("What is your B? ")
C = input("What is your C? ")
a = int(A)
b = int(B)
c = int(C)
def Quad_pt1():
    Pt1 = b*-1
    return Pt1
def Quad_pt2():
    Pt2 = math.sqrt(pow(2, b)-(4*a*c))
    return Pt2
def Quad_pt3():
    Pt3 = 2*a
    return Pt3
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt1())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt2())
t3 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt3())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
print(t1, t2, t3)
exit()
print((Pt1+Pt2)/Pt3)
print((Pt1-Pt2)/Pt3)
```

I have the exit function there to terminate before the other print statements as I don't need them right now. My output is:

```
What is your a? 23
What is your B? 26
What is your C? 73
<Thread(Thread-1, stopped 6149271552)> <Thread(Thread-2, stopped 6166097920)> <Thread(Thread-3, stopped 6182924288)>
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-3    self.run()
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
: 'float' object is not callable
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It would also helpful to find a fix for handling numbers that would result in a squaring issue:

```
What is your a? 1
What is your B? 1
What is your C? 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many math solvers/quadratic formula.py", line 19, in <module>
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt2())
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sterlingrussell/PycharmProjects/many math solvers/quadratic formula.py", line 13, in Quad_pt2
    Pt2 = math.sqrt(pow(2, b)-(4*a*c))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: math domain error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In some cases, I get an error saying that my integer is too big to convert to float. Any suggestions on how to fix that? I realize I will not be dealing with numbers greater than 100k, but the program should be able to handle large inputs.

Comment: You are getting `math domain error` because `pow(2, b)-(4*a*c)` is negative inside the sqrt. You are filling `a=1,b=1,c=1`.

Comment: `target=Quad_pt1()` should be `target=Quad_pt1`. You're calling the function immediately, not in the thread.

Comment: If you want complex roots you can use `cmath.sqrt(pow(2, b)-(4*a*c))`.

Comment: `Pt1`, `Pt2`, and `Pt3` are local variables in the functions, you can't access them when calculating the result. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread

Comment: how do i store the outputs of the threads now?

Comment: pow(2, b) is 2^b not b^2, assuming that you are trying to calculate b^2 - 4*a*c

Comment: @cococ0x i'm trying to square b, not trying to put 2 to the power of b

Comment: @SterlingRussell Follow my link, it shows how to return results from threads. As a worst case you could declare them as global variables.

Comment: @SterlingRussell yes, that is exactly what I am trying to say. your code pow(2,b) = 2^b. you should've write pow(b,2) to get b^2.

Comment: @Barmar why is using a global variable the worst case?

Comment: As a general rule, global variables are poor design. Functions should get their parameters through arguments, and return values, so they can be used in a variety of contexts.

Comment: You can use floats for a, b and c if you really want to solve most quadratics. Also by convention, follow PEP 8 guidelines. For example, a more pythonic approach would be to name Quad_pt1 `quad_pt1`

Comment: As an aside, did you consider complex roots in your program? Some quadratics have complex roots so you might want to `import cmath` as well.

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://github.com/journpy/quadratic_equation_solver_oop as it solves all quadratics whether real or complex roots. Also skim through https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ for Style Guides for your Python Code

Comment: Why on earth are you using threads for these trivial functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: Thank you @Mark Tolonen for pointing out that the order of the threads do not guarantee the order. Since the threads can complete at any time, they may be appended to `result` out of order. Implementing a dictionary and using explicit keys guarantees the values to be where we expect.*

Like @Barmar said, you can return results from threads, *or* declare them as global variables (since that's what `a`, `b`, and `c` are already doing). ***For a quick solution** with some fixes, here's the latter:

```
import math
import threading

A = input("What is your A? ")
B = input("What is your B? ")
C = input("What is your C? ")
a = float(A) # used floats here for fractional inputs (try .5, -2.5, 2)
b = float(B)
c = float(C)

result = {}

def Quad_pt1():
    Pt1 = b * -1
    result["Pt1"] = Pt1


def Quad_pt2():
    Pt2 = math.sqrt(b**2 - (4 * a * c))
    result["Pt2"] = Pt2

def Quad_pt3():
    Pt3 = 2 * a
    result["Pt3"] = Pt3

t1 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt2)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=Quad_pt3)

thread_list = [t1, t2, t3]

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.start()

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

t1, t2, t3 = result["Pt1"], result["Pt2"], result["Pt3"]
```

Output:

```
What is your A? .5
What is your B? -2.5
What is your C? 2
2.5 1.5 1.0
```

**While the code works, try to make use of best practices (you'll pick them up the more you do!)*

Comment: i noticed that you are converting A B and C with float and not int, is there a benefit to using float?

Comment: @SterlingRussell the quadratic formula can take in fractions for inputs (for example, see the caption on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#/media/File:Quadratic_roots.svg). Or, any function that gives you real solutions, you can divide by any real number and still get a real solution (math experts may prove me wrong...).

Comment: There's no guarantee that the returned results will always be in the same order.