# Await a threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

I have defined a function which is set to send a message to a Discord channel every hour. This would be run alongside your typical `on_message()` commands, so I thought of putting the reccuring function inside a thread using threading.

I tried to async/await the thread as you do, but it didn't work. How do I make it possible so I could have a message repeat every hour along with typical commands?

My code is as follows

```
async def reccur_func():
    while 1:
        await reccurship()
        time.sleep(30)

client = discord.Client()

threading.Thread(target = reccur_func).start()   #I tried putting await and async at the beginning of this line

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):

    ......

client.run('....')
```

Thank you all

Comment: as a trivial note, 'recurrence' might be the word you were looking for :p (and 'recur' only has one C)

Comment: What is the coroutine `reccurship` that you are waiting on? Also, `reccur_func()` doesn't look like it does anything. It simply waits for another routine and then sleeps.

Comment: @Personman thank you very much. My spelling/grammar is the best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the exact question but it worked in my case.

In discord I used `client.loop.create_task(reccur_func())` and it executed that funcion (Which repeat itself) while continuing to run everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be mixing up AsyncIO with threading.

If you want to use AsyncIO, you will need to add a task for `reccur_func()` to the event loop. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512182/how-can-i-periodically-execute-a-function-with-asyncio) will provide some more details.

If you want to use threading, remove the `await` from `reccur_func()`:

```py
def reccur_func():
    while 1:
        # Do something
        time.sleep(30)
```

You can find some more info about threading [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241099/executing-tasks-in-parallel-in-python).

Comment: The problem is I need to use await as otherwise I am not able to send a message with discord.

Answer (score 0):

The [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) way to do this is to use the `discord.ext.tasks` extension to turn `reccurship` into a [task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def reccurship():
    ...

@reccurship.before_loop
async def before_reccurship():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

recurrship.start()

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: I used a different method but it was practically the same as your one. I used `client.loop.create_task(reccur_func())`.