# How to access the values returned from threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.x

I'm new to [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) using Python 2.7.6. I need to get the values returned by my threads after starting them.

My code is as follow :

```
from threading import Thread
from functions import *

class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, index,ip,t,i=1):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip_dst = ip
        self.t = t

    def run(self):
        value_back = execute(self.ip_dst,self.t,i=1)
        return value_back
```

The **execute_client function** is executed **by every Thread**. I want to get the **value_back** for each thread at the end and store them let's say in a list data structure. The **execute function** is inside the **functions module** I wrote.

I looked at this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread) but did not understand how to adapt the answer for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adopted from the link you posted, you should do something like this:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from functions import *

class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, someargs, queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        value_back = execute(self.ip_dst,self.t,i=1)
        self.queue.put(value_back)

myqueue = Queue.Queue
myclient = Client(someargs, myqueue)
myclient.start()
```

And fetch the results via:

```
fetch = myqueue.get()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But do I need to do myclient.join() or not ?

Comment: @user2567806 See this https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects (section Join): joining the thread makes the base thread pause until myclient has terminated. Like this, the program stops, when every thread finished execution.

Comment: So basically, yes, you should, at the end of the program.

Comment: This is the error I've got when I added myclient.join(): RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started.
So I conclude that when we call directly the run method we do not need to do a join, right ? Because I did not use start() method for the thread.

Comment: I executed the code and surprisingly the Threads are not started concurrently ^-^. They are executed one after one. I do not understand Why, is that because of I call run() method instead of start () ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault. You need to call start() which then calls the run() method itself. Like this, the run() method is started in a separate thread

Comment: As you cannot pass arguments through the start method to the run method, you should pass the queue to the constructor. Gonna edit my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it now, thank you so much guys.
What I did is as follows :

`from Queue import Queue`

`from threading import Thread`

`from functions import *`

`class Client(Thread):
def __init__(self,myqueue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myqueue = myqueue
def run(self):
        value_back = execute(self.ip_dst,self.t,i=1)
        self.myqueue.put(value_back)`

And it worked.

Regards guys.