# How to get multiple return values from a threaded function?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, return, return-value

Have called an external function which returns multiple values.

```
def get_name(full_name):
   # you code
   return first_name, last_name
```

In simple function call, I can get the results.

```
from names import get_name

first, last= get_name(full_name)
```

But I need to use threading for the call to get the result values for the first and last variables. I failed in using a simple threading call.

```
first, last= Threading.thread(get_name, args= (full_name,)
```

Please help me to get the return values of the function call

Comment: using a queue and pusing them there instead of returning them.

Comment: What was the nature of the failure exactly? If you got an error, could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the return value from a thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) for retrieve data from threads, here you have an example using a wrapper to store values from the functions into a queue:

```
import threading
import queue

my_queue = queue.Queue()

def storeInQueue(f):
  def wrapper(*args):
    my_queue.put(f(*args))
  return wrapper


@storeInQueue
def get_name(full_name):
   return full_name, full_name



t = threading.Thread(target=get_name, args = ("foo", ))
t.start()

my_data = my_queue.get()
print(my_data)
```

Here you have the [live working example](https://repl.it/repls/DigitalGrimyPackage)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: this is overkill, concurrent.futures would be better

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`pool.apply_async()`** of **`ThreadPool()`** to return **the multiple values** from **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def test(arg1, arg2):
    return 'a', 1, arg1, arg2

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1) # Here
result = pool.apply_async(test, ('b', 2)) # Here
print(result.get()) # ('a', 1, 'b', 2)
```

And, you can also use **`submit()`** of **`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`** to return **the multiple values** from **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def test(arg1, arg2):
    return 'a', 1, arg1, arg2

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: # Here
    future = executor.submit(test, 'b', 2) # Here
    print(future.result()) # ('a', 1, 'b', 2)
```