# simple Multi-threading in python not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I managed to come up with the following code, which will allow me to query a data file twice, simultaneously for different information.  but, it doesnt seem to be working.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

```
print('Start')
def getAllTimes(arg1):
    task1 = arg1
    if task1 == 1:
        textfile = open(logfile, 'r')
        filetext = textfile.read()
        textfile.close()
        matchesBegin = beginStr in filetext
        matchesEnd = endStr in filetext
        return(matchesBegin,matchesEnd)
    elif task1 == 2:
        AllTimeStamps = [ x.split(' ')[0][1:-1] for x in open(logfile).readlines() ]
        AllUniqTimeStamps = set(AllTimeStamps)
        return AllUniqTimeStamps
etime = 0
AllTimes = []
for etime in range(1,2):
    AllTimeZ = threading.Thread(target=getAllTimes, args=[etime])
    AllTimes.append(AllTimeZ)
    AllTimeZ.start()
for TheTimes in AllTimes:
    TheTimes.join()
    print TheTimes
print('Done')
```

After the above code runs, I want to make sure I can query the content of any variables created in the functions.  And by variables I mean:  `matchesBegin, matchesEnd, AllUniqTimestamps`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return value from thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread)

Comment: certainly not a duplicate

Comment: It is a duplicate - your question boils down to asking how to return values from your threads and the linked question talks precisely about that.