# threaded functions work in parallel return none

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have tow functions I want to run in same time, put this is returning none none

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    return('Working')

def func2():
    return("Working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    str1=Thread(target = func1).start()
    str2=Thread(target = func2).start()
    print(str1,str2)
```

How can I make two functions work in parallel  and return some values ?

Comment: You might want to use ``concurrent.futures`` instead of the lower-level ``threading`` module.

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) say `Thread.start()` will return?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886090/return-value-from-thread